# Review ban due to a question with several upvotes and reopen votes

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-suspension

Three of us seem to have been banned due to this question appearing in the low-quality review queue:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4994041

The question seems to have achieved 5 upvotes, 4 reopen votes as of now, and some people have also agreed with our decision in the tavern chat. Also, the reviewers modulo agreed on "Looks OK".

I agree that it is not the best question ever, but on the other hand the OP posted some code, and got an answer which has been found useful by some.

I do not agree with the close vote there personally, but I accept and respect the mod's decision. Also, the question seems to have been beyond the track record of the closer as well as mine. I am not sure whether that weights here much, but I just wanted to raise that regardless.

However, I personally think review ban for the contributors for such a question, which does not seem to be clear-case, is a bit excessive.

Is it just me thinking so?

I personally think there are worse situations (i.e. clear-case) in the suggested edit queue for instance, but elsewhere, too, where ban does not get applied.

Also, please note that I do not wish to get unbanned and so on. I am just merely thinking whether reviewers should be handled like that in general for cases like this.

Comment: I could be wrong here, but I was pretty sure that you were not automatically review-banned after *one* failed review. There are false positives/negatives.

Comment: @CodyGray: as far as I can tell, it was a manual ban, not automatic. I have not failed any audits for the time. The moderator in question (not the one who closed it now after the reopen by the community) closed it as unclear around those minutes, so he probably went through the people to ban them manually.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I can understand Shog's desire to keep reviewers on their toes and reviewing appropriately, and I understand why he issued the review bans for this item. It should also be noted that the review bans for only for **one day**. It is an effective method for moderators to send a message to reviewers and indicate a specific review task, providing an avenue for learning experiences while not inconveniencing a user for an extended period of time, **and we're definitely starting to use them a lot more often** now that we can include such messages.

In this particular case, it is a bit difficult to tell how horrible this question is, and [I've explained why the question makes no sense in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071787/php4-to-php5-conversion-sprintf-issue#comment37127513_24071787). The question definitely deserves to remain closed, there's no questioning that.

However, I believe that the purpose of the review ban has already been served. We wanted you to see something, and you saw it. Considering that this was such an edge case that could easily confuse someone, I personally don't see any reason why the ban should remain in effect past this point, and I have removed it for you.

Comment: Thanks for removing the ban, although the problem is that I am not sure if it can be avoided in the future. People have different opinions about different things. Different opinion should not deserve banning. Whether it is through ban or mod messages in clear-case situations, that is fine for me either way, but my point is the clear-case. I think it should only be applied in clear-case situations, but this is just my two cents.

Comment: …isn't there a better way of communicating than bans?

Comment: @bjb568 We used to send mod messages if there was atrocious behavior, but that was ineffective because, while we were communicating a problem, we weren't actively *preventing* them from taking further action, even if temporarily. Letting us review ban someone with a message ensures they see the message *and* take a break to think about it. Much more effective.

Comment: I've never heard of a kid getting shoved in a corner for a timeout lasting 24 hours, especially when it isn't a clear-cut right and wrong.

Comment: Not really related to the issue at hand here, but does *"and we're definitely starting to use them a lot more often"* mean I can flag all reviewers who I think did a bad review? Up till now I've only flagged exceptional cases.

Comment: @bjb568 When you're punishing your kid they're right there in the room with you and you know they got the message because you just told them. Online, we don't know how long it will be before they even return to the review queues again.

Comment: @Stijn We're being more stringent with the application of review bans, but I don't think our flags queue can handle an influx of minor cases of review abuse, so sticking to more exceptional cases is better.

Comment: @animuson By them performing a request for information from the server *you own*?

Comment: @bjb568 If we ban someone for an hour and they don't even return to the site for, say, 8 hours, then our ban had absolutely no effect whatsoever. Considering that review resets daily, it makes sense to just ban for a day, and they'll probably be back at some point within that 24 hour timeframe.

Comment: @animuson Yeah, so measure an hour (or something) after reading the message.

Comment: @bjb568 Write up a feature request if you want.

Comment: @animuson I don't care enough to do it. I'm just point out that it doesn't make any sense. Alternatively, you can put a big *warning* in front of their faces. Very intrusive and annoying, but not a *ban*.

Comment: difficult to explain, how's that? [First revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24071787/1) looks perfect fit for unclear / lacks info to diagnose closure: _"PHP4 to PHP5 conversion sprintf issue. -- I am trying to convert my old php code to PHP 5 but i am facing problems with the sprintf command. This is my old code. `<dump>` This is my new code: `<dump>` where `$phpspry` is the link and `$database_phpspry` is the db name. Please suggest a solution since the codes which dont have sprintf are working properly."_

Comment: @animuson, is that question *so horrible* that you've had to lock it ? Or what is the purpose of the lock there ?

Comment: @TLama I'd venture a guess that locking is to tame [meta effect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204311/165773 "'Increase of voting activities observed in main site posts that have been exposed at meta'"). Notice on the question currently says "locked while disputes about its content are being resolved"

Comment: @gnat, oh, I missed that text. Thanks! That reminds me one question I've seen a few days ago with the same text. Locked since the end of the last year...

Comment: @TLama when I spot a post with content dispute lock that appears to hang for too long, I typically flag this for mod attention (and yeah, it's hard to imagine content dispute taking several months:)

Comment: Just remember: skipping question in the queue is also a valid option: if you don't know or don't care, I'd suggest to skip instead of using Looks OK as the default.

Comment: In this case, there is no evidence to support an opinion that the question is good. (1) There is no actual question, just a bunch of code with no mention of what is expected and what is actually happening. (2) Given some knowledge of PHP, it is apparent that there is nothing wrong with the usage of `sprintf` in the code. On that basis, the question makes no sense. (3) The answers that it got are not valuable. One mentions that `sprintf` is not necessary which is true, but is not going to fix the problem. The second claims that the cause is `sprintf` needing more arguments, which is not true.

Answer (score -7):

Ask yourself two things:

1. Is the question good as-is?
2. If it could be made good with an edit, did you edit?

#### Is the question good as-is?

Here are the guidelines from the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask):

1. Write a title that summarizes the specific problem
2. Introduce the problem before you post any code
3. Help others reproduce the problem

For all three tests, this question fails. *"PHP4 to PHP5 conversion `sprintf` issue"* does not explain the problem, because as animuson points out *" You mention removing sprintf makes it work properly, but from the code samples you've provided, I can definitely say that they do work."* which means it also fails #3 (the problem can't be reproduced). There is definitely no introduction to the problem other than *"I am trying to convert my old PHP code to PHP 5 but I am facing problems with the sprintf command. This is my old code."*

Did you test the code, confirm that the question was valid/good as asked?

#### Could it have been made better with an edit?

Even you realize that it isn't the best question:

> I agree that it is not the best question ever, but on the other hand the OP posted some code, and got an answer which has been found useful by some.

If you know it can be improved, and it isn't the best question, then why did you click *"Looks OK"*? You seem to be implying that you looked at the answer (which isn't shown in the queue I believe), but yet you didn't take a few minutes to edit it when you knew it needed improvement? [Stijn made a noble attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24071787/revisions), but that didn't end up fixing it.

#### So why was what happened unfair?

1. You said the post was good when it wasn't
2. You didn't bother to fix it when you knew it wasn't

It seems to me that there are important lessons you could take away from this prior to saying that things are unfair because other people screwed up too. What exactly makes you think that being punished for a mistake you admit to after the fact isn't fair?

Comment: This is a misinterpration of my sentence, even if unintentionally, I am afraid. For sure, "Not the best question" is not equal to "Not OK". There is a difference between "OK" and "best question". Have you considered that option I had nothing to add to the question, it just was not the most important for me to answer, thus not the best? You intepreted my intent your way, that is fine, but now I am clarifying, it should not be interpreted one way. If you are not sure what I meant by "not best", ask for clarification. In fact, I even left comments that were cleaned up in the meantime.

Comment: Apologies if you feel I misinterpreted you @Final. The guidance in our [help] makes it clear that it doesn't fit the bill for what explain to users as a 'good question'. Do you disagree that this question doesn't fit the guidelines in the help center? (If so, that's where the disconnect lies)

Comment: I will say that I feel this question as something that could be useful for others, hence I decided not to close, and other people had the same opinion. But that is fine if we disagree. What I find suboptimal is the ban personally in cases where people disagree so much, and almost in equal range, +6/-6 as of now, and +4 for the answer, +3 saying "Looks OK". It was even stranger around the ban time. It was even reopened once by the community (5 people).

Comment: @Final Were you able to reproduce the issue, and confirm that the upvoted answer actually solves the issue as stated? If the problem can't be reproduced as described by someone who tried (animuson), how is the question useful? If it can be reproduced, and solved as stated, then wouldn't the question be more useful if edited in a way that allows experienced users (like animuson) reproduce it easily?

Comment: Imho your reasoning here doesn't really answer the question. The question was not about whether this is a valid close vote or if the OP could have done thinks better. The questions is about the review ban and if it is not a bit excessive (which I think it is). If we would ban everyone from reviewing, who is not doing 100%, there would be nearly no-one left. There is much more misuse going on which is not punished in such a way, so this should not either.

Comment: @dirkk, I'm not writing to determine whether the original asker's ban was proper or not (I do not know if there was a history, if there was additional context, etc.), and I don't think it's much use to theorize or share my opinion (which means naught in this case). What I do want to do is point out that looking at it objectively, there seem to be issues with the content of the question, and with the result of the reviews, and that it may be beneficial for Final (or anyone else) to consider that when reviewing/reading questions. Maybe you don't find use in that, but I hope some reviewers do.

Comment: Offtopic, but: "If you know it can be improved, and it isn't the best question, then why did you click "Looks OK"?" - It's been discussed elsewhere that 'looks ok' is a bad way express things and needs to be changed, and what it really means is "it's not so bad that it should be deleted/closed". It doesn't have to be a good one for it to not be closed, just good enough.

Comment: @jmac Why should a reviewer of the close vote queue go through such depths? Personally I think the validity of an answer should not be a determining factor to close a question(!). I am not sure what I would have done with this question; I'd probably have skipped it.

Comment: @Mark, I agree that having an incorrect answer doesn't mean the question is bad, Final said, *"I agree that it is not the best question ever, but on the other hand the OP posted some code, **and got an answer which has been found useful by some.**"* If you are going to use an answer as a plus for the post, I'd hope it actually solves the problem as posted. I may have clicked skip as well, but if that had been done in this case, we wouldn't have this meta post in the first place.

Comment: _"I'm not writing to determine whether the original asker's ban was proper or not"_ As this is the exact question the OPs ask, you are simply not answering the question. As you set some high standards for the OP in your answers I think you should hold yourself to the same standards. And the help center specifically states that answer are to be deleted if they not even partial answer the actual question - Which is the case here, as you stated yourself.