# Approved suggested edit from a known troll?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, review-suspension

Just got a message on my review queue:

> You approved an inappropriate code formatting edit from a known troll:
> https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5288856 . Please do
> not accept random code edits from anonymous users.
>
> Come back in 2 days to continue reviewing.

Now, the code review was just for a code formatting, and 3 other reviewers also approved it.

How was I supposed to know the user was a known troller? If the user IS a know troller, then why is he/she allowed to edit posts?

Comment: See this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265564/1590950

Comment: See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265560/is-community-auto-modifying-code-indentations-now) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263115/when-is-it-okay-to-edit-answers-for-code-formatting) to learn the background for your message. [This](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/263121/3580294) answer should clearly answer your question -- namely, edits should *objectively* make the question better, and edits simply changing code styles do not qualify as an objective improvement.

Comment: @user3580294: It doesn't clearly answer any question.  The edit changed the post from a bizarre indentation style (close brace gets 5 spaces, open brace gets 4???) to something more commonly used.

Comment: @tmyklebu Yeah, that was entirely my fault. Took a look and assumed it was normal C# style, but missed the mismatched spacing, and so didn't really catch the rationale behind the question. Unfortunately, it was too late to edit, but I thought the links to previous Meta questions about this particular user were enough to keep the comment around. Should I still remove that comment and perhaps repost with the links?

Comment: @user3580294: Your links contribute to the discussion and provide context for why the ban was issued in the first place.  I just don't think it's relevant to the "is this ridiculous?" question
.

Comment: @tmyklebu You are correct. I'll have to be sure to read the question more carefully in the future... Thank you for pointing that out to me.

Comment: 2 days?  I would have preferred a (much) longer break.

Comment: @devnull: Why? It is clear that Alexandre did not accept an overly rubbish edit intentionally. I mean, I would not have approved this myself because changing personal taste can go on for an eternity, but this is not the type of approval that deserves much longer break, I think. In particular, Alexandre is even here for learning. I do not notice any intentionally destructive behavior here.

Comment: I would have approved the edit as well. It is minor, but there is very little to be changed, and better code readability is always nice. (would it only be the unmatching open and close brackets indentation)

Comment: @njzk2: yeah, I cannot understand the people repeating "too minor". It is either valid or invalid for the reason, but not too minor as there is not much else to improve in that post. Alternatively, custom decline message could also do it, e.g.: `It is a subjective change which can go on for an eternity, so do not do it`.

Comment: @FinalContest I would find edit suggestions that simply change the position of braces from the `if` line to the following one or vice versa to be pretty amusing.  People have their own preferences regarding that, and suggesting edits that do not change anything except the position of braces __must__ be rejected as __too minor__.  Feed the reviewers something better.

Comment: I'm glad that there isn't any rep for reviewing edits.  Stop giving those badges too and then one would see that there are no reviewers.

Comment: @devnull: I _think_ you do not get the meaning of too minor along with some other similar people here: it means that _IMHO_ the edit is useful, but it did not address all the valid concerns in the post. Now, if you claim that preference style is not useful, it cannot be too minor by its definition, but invalid or custom reason to be nice (see above).

Comment: @devnull: there is also the matter of the unmatching indentation (4 for the opening bracket vs 5 for the closing one)

Comment: @njzk2 OK.  So it must be an exemplary edit.  I'll start into 5 old posts to find instances of _not-so-well_ indented pieces of code.

Comment: @devnull there has to be a variety of middle grounds to find between utterly useless and/or subjective change and totally awesome change that improve the syntax, the formatting, and also makes the question so much easier to understand. Such as slightly improving edit that does not damage the post, but rather improves it, however small that is (in particular when there is not really much left to improve in it).

Comment: @devnull: and if you have time to spend to fix indentation of old pieces of code, knock yourself out. I don't see much good reason to prevent you from doing that.

Comment: @njzk2 "...  however small that is ..." -- in that event, I recommend holding on until one gains the required privilege.  Such edits are lousy and utter waste of everybody's time if those need to be reviewed.

Comment: @devnull : `waste of (...) time if those need to be reviewed` agreed on that part.

Comment: If there's nothing else to fix and the edit only changes code formatting from one religion to another, then the change is too minor. There's no reason to touch such a question (or answer).

Comment: For what it's worth, thank you for bringing the 4/5 space difference to my attention. I've gone ahead and fixed it myself; it was not intentional, and I'm assuming was some sort of copy/paste error.

Comment: And i just fixed it again after another slightly overzealous rollback.  Would people please make sure they're not reverting formatting improvements done *by the post's author*?  :P

Answer (score 115, accepted):

As you can tell from my answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265564/19679), I was the one who temporarily banned you from review. I want to at least explain my reasoning here.

As was indicated [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263115/when-is-it-okay-to-edit-answers-for-code-formatting), a particular user is being targeted by an imaginative troll. This childish individual seems to believe that Raven Dreamer's code style is wrong, and has decided to "correct" their posts. We eventually had to suspend their main account to stop them from harassing Raven Dreamer with unwanted edits. They then took to anonymous edits to troll Raven Dreamer with code edits they knew wouldn't be liked, and found that reviewers immediately approved them.

We've tried all kinds of means of stopping them, from locking the original answer (which was edited 6 times by an anonymous source before we locked it) to lower-level measures. They've worked around all these, and reviewers kept approving these edits.

Anonymous edits should be scrutinized very carefully, particularly when it comes to code edits. Frankly, I don't think we should trust any edits of code coming from anonymous sources, because I've seen an awful lot of vandalism come in that way.

I also do not believe edits that only change someone's code style should be approved. Unless they obviously messed things up, making code unreadable, code style is a matter of personal preference and we should respect that preference.

I may have gotten a little frustrated after seeing edit after edit get approved like this, thus the terse language, but the messages were merely intended to be informative. The reason for the 2-day ban is that this was happening over the weekend, and I didn't want the message to go away before people had a chance to see it. I just wanted people to read the message and know why I thought it was inappropriate to approve edits like this.

I'm sorry for the trouble this caused, and I probably should have linked back to the ongoing Meta discussions about these edits in my message to make what I said about a "known troll" clearer. I've lifted your ban, since the message was received. I just wanted to do something to stop the harassment of this user by this childish vandal.

Comment: The reviewers might have seen this coming, had they been reading Meta for the past few days.

Comment: How about making this post "featured"? Increased awareness might help combat the troll

Comment: Should we get a link to this post when an anonymous review appears in the reviewing queue?

Comment: Solution: ban anon edits, end of. I, like minitech, don't think this reviewer should have been banned. There was no way of him knowing that the edit was, a. trolling and b. from a troll. So what if some people don't like that coding style, some do; are we to decide improvement because some comment from a guy who doesn't like Egyptian braces is heavily upvoted? There was no notification at all unless someone has  just sits on meta all day reading all the articles. He should have been warned of the meta discussion.

Comment: @Sammaye: banning aside, the problem here is that you should not edit a post (or approve an edit to a post) just to change the braces style. Whether the person doing the edit is a troll or not does not change anything. I hate Egyptian braces, but if one likes to use them, good on them, I will not change that.

Comment: @nico many would argue that the spacing being inconsistent was reason for edit, I mean as some say, the opening brace had 4 spaces while the ending brace had 5 and other spacing inconsistencies. The review seemed as though someone just came along and fixed that

Comment: @Sammaye: in other cases I may agree with you, but I don't see how 4 spaces vs 5 spaces make the code unreadeable, and was not posing any problem whatsoever for people to understand the issue.

Comment: @nico Normally I would agree with you too however, these types of edits are not rare and are regularly accepted and in my time here I don't think I have ever seen one disputed. Considering how zealous certain individuals are about code formatting (myself included), the bad formatting of the code might not have hindered readability but it sure would have annoyed me, enough to detract me from the question at hand

Comment: @Sammaye: in that case the "correct" edit to do would have been putting 4 spaces everywhere (or 5 spaces), not to change the coding style.

Comment: @Brad: I am sorry for stating the obvious, but don't you guys have a better way to communicate trolls and unintentionally mistaken approvals in this case than **banning** people? This is a recurring pattern and some users get sick of it all understandably. I do not mean to defend the robo-reviewers, but yeah, Alexandre is apparently not one of them.

Comment: So I will get banned too for one single mistake? Because I would have approved such edit as well. It's improving the post quality, period. I do not check the history of all past suggestions.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Edits that only change someone's coding style should not be approved, particularly if they are coming from an anonymous source. In this case "banned" is perhaps a little harsh, since the reviewers were only warned and prevented from reviewing for a couple of days at worst. This didn't harm them in any other way, just served as a warning not to approve these specific edits.

Comment: @BradLarson code indentation is not about styling, there is no point leaving blank space in the beginning of each line. It's no different than fixing grammar, in my opinion. Good point about anonymous edits though, and post being old also playing a role.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think what I have gathered from here is that the difference between styling and formatting is the new line for the braces. The spacing is fine to delete, but you leave that new line alone else that starts a fight between parts of the site...yeah, kinda sad but true. It also means that I have gone a step too far many times as well, unwittingly of course

Comment: @ShadowWizard "Code indentation is not about styling" - ever heard the phrase "*code indentation style*"?

Comment: So, we *have* to keep abreast of meta, and the current crop of problem users, now, or face being banned from tasks that improve the site? Why are anonymous edits allowed, if the frequency of vandalism, and the risk to (even careful) reviewers, is so high?

Comment: @BradLarson: come on... assume some intelligence about Alexandre and similar people. They _do_ understand the reasons without a couple of days banning, or much longer as suggested in another comment. [Surely, there should be a more civil way for moderators and "mistaken" people to communicate without all the public buzz for each case containing the names and potential shame](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258581/review-ban-due-to-a-question-with-several-upvotes-and-reopen-votes#comment36969_258584).

Comment: but the indentation did not match!

Comment: @FinalContest - Up until recently, we didn't even have a means of providing a custom message to reviewers, only timed bans. If you have a suggestion for tools or other ways of instructing reviewers about problematic approvals, please do suggest one. The ban was secondary to the message I was trying to convey, and I only timed it to be long enough for people to see it after the weekend. If we could present a message to someone (without using moderator messages that permanently annotate your account) without a review ban, I certainly would have used it in this case.

Comment: I agree with many of the comments here, if the problem seems to be approving suggested edits by an anonymous source, why are those anonymous sources allowed to suggest edits at all?

Comment: @BradLarson: I appreciate that the tool is the problem, but that is not a reason not to get the tool improved. **The tool should exist to help the contributors, not to annoy them.** If only the annotation is your issue, well, how about talking to Mr. Heyer to introduce a type of moderator message that does not annotate?

Comment: "If we could present a message to someone" - good idea for a feature suggestion. We need to be careful that the accidental terseness of a human-originated message (especially if there is a ban attached to it) does not put people off reviewing.

Comment: @devnull: What exactly is unclear about Alexandre's response?

Comment: +1 for thoroughly explaining your reasoning, -3 for the action taken to remedy the situation. Banning should be used as a last resort when it is indisputable that there's no other alternative. I don't edit often, but now I'm genuinely scared of contributing to the site knowing that a single mistake could cost me a ban. That's the type of signal you guys are sending to the users.

Comment: There are so many basic actions (even voting up answers to questions **you** asked yourself) that require a minimum reputation, I don't understand why anonymous users would be allowed to do **anything** but asking a question

Comment: It seems like the general response lately is to chastise people for not reading minutiae on meta everyday before trying to contribute. Otherwise it is seemingly impossible to know what the mods want.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the idea that reviewers have to stay abreast of meta discussions else risk losing privileges just seems obviously and totally unworkable.

Comment: As far as i understand, noone was actually banned. All he was banned from doing was doing reviews for two days, including a weekend. How is that an overly harsh response for approving an edit that (except for one space missmatch) only changed the indention style of the post? Does anyone consider reviewing edits the reason they come to SO? Do we really want edit wars about indention style?

Comment: @DeVadder It's overly harsh because, for someone who isn't up to date on the meta posts about the troll, they can get banned for failing a single review audit. Not a pattern of failed audits, but one. And not scaring people off edits is important - if users are afraid to help improve posts (hyperbole ahead), we'll have VLQ questions/answers everywhere. Take a look at l46kok's comment above: `... I don't edit often, but now I'm genuinely scared of contributing to the site knowing that a single mistake could cost me a ban. That's the type of signal you guys are sending to the users.`

Comment: @thegrinner 1: This is about reviews. l46kok now being afraid of editing has little to do with it. 2. They did not get banned. The Op was stopped from *reviewing edits* for two days. They could have asked questions, answered and even edited to their hearts content. They just got told "Please stop approving edits that change nothing but indention style." and kept from approving more for two days so the message could arrive (as it was very possible the Op was a robot). Yes, the mod did miss the *single space* that also got removed and admitted to have gone too fast. I don't see the issue, sorry.

Comment: @DeVadder Sorry, char limit meant I wasn't entirely clear - reviewing edits and actually editing are somewhat synonymous for cleaning up VLQ content. If people are afraid to review edits, then the edits of users <2k and anons won't be handled. And I think you should take another look at the message OP received - `You approved an inappropriate code formatting edit from a known troll` doesn't say the same thing as "Please stop approving edits that change nothing but indentation style." My main point is a 2 day edit ban is way over the top for something that would normally get a (continued...)

Comment: ...(continued) get a "Stop! Look again!" for a normal review audit. Whether or not OP is a robo-reviewer, a 2 day review suspension for what is effectively a single failed audit is extremely harsh.

Comment: @DeVadder And just to be clear, I'm not trying to suggest the edit in question was OK - I think we all agree any added value was negligible and subjective (at best). I just wanted to comment on the harshness of the original response.

Comment: @thegrinner Yes, the original message may not have been the best, as BradLarson mentioned as well. All i wanted to express is that i feel that a lot of the comments here are way overstating the severeness of the punishment. Just calling it a ban implies that the OP was banned from SO, not just from *reviewing edits*. And i cannot understand how that would scare anyone from reviewing. If the worst thing to happen after a mistake during reviewing is a review ban, in what way would that scare one away from reviewing in the first place? Worst outcome is you stop and lose nothing. Anyways: Bye

Comment: When it comes to handing out punishment, the severess of the punishment should be proportionate to the offense. On top of that, it's the message delivered to the public by the admin that's of an importance here - if admins have powers to ban a user from reviewing after a single mistake, what's there to stop them from banning the users from SO entirely? You might argue this is unlikely to happen, but at least this is the type of impression the users will receive.

Answer (score 24):

The suggested edit was in no way too minor – troll suggester or not – and your review was correct.

I strongly disagree with your ban, but I won’t change it without further discussion.

Comment: Changing brace style with no other changes is appropriate?

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: Removing excessive, incorrect indentation is appropriate.

Comment: Who is to say that the prior indentation was "incorrect?"  That's a style call, and as far as I'm aware, there is not a SO style guide.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: It’s almost certainly not intended to be indented that far – a common paste error – and it’s further inconsistent within itself (compare the class and method braces). In other words, it looks stupid, and the suggested edit was an improvement.

Comment: This particular user has been targeted with his posts being changed to "Egyption Braces" on many questions.  That and nothing else.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: How is a reviewer to know that? How is a ban fair? The edit does make an improvement, and there’s not much else to change in the question.

Comment: I disagree that the edit is an improvement.  I abhor "Egyption Braces" in (almost) any code.  Others do too.  Persumably the OP of that question is in that camp.  And if there's nothing else to change in the question, it should not have been edited.

Comment: @false: Please be aware that some style guides put braces on the same line only for the function or only for the class. So that's not neccessarily an inconsistently applied style. Regarding that the whole class definition (aside from the first line) was indented, there's a style doing such as well, though I have my doubts that's the reason. I would concurr that's a paste error, but that's only a small part of the restyling done.

Comment: Whether or not is was a paste error, whether or not the OP intended to have the body indented the post was not illegible in any way because of it. I'd vote to reject this edit as too minor too. Code style is the OP's choice and as long as the post is still clear and understandable it should be left alone.

Comment: I agree, there is nothing wrong with this edit.

Comment: @Mehrdad there is nothing *wrong* with it... but that doesn't mean it's not *too minor*, which it is

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: The close brace at the end was indented five spaces when the matching open brace was indented four.  Maybe someone does this intentionally somewhere, but...eeek.

Comment: @VotetoClose Fixing just a small problem, if it's the only problem in a post, isn't too minor.  If "there is nothing wrong with this edit" then it adds some value.  As [you pointed out](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265571/approved-code-review-from-a-known-troll?cb=1#comment60661_265572), it's mostly a good post, so there's not much left to fix about it.  If the edit *missed* a bunch of problems, then it would be too minor.  If it addressed all the problems in the post, then it's not too minor.

Comment: @tmyklebu, the very fact that we're arguing the difference a single space makes just screams "too minor" to me. I also think we're missing the point of the reject reason and the rep bar for reviewed or immediate edits. If you have +2k rep and full edit privileges go ahead and correct a minor indentation issue (as long as you don't break the question or apply your own opinions or preferences above the OP's own ones). You only use your own time. However, anyone below the rep limit is asked to only make "substantial" edits as they are using other users' time too.

Comment: @indivisible: Where is that documented?  The help centre says the **exact opposite**---see http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing .

Comment: Which indentation style is better is just people's opinions, the only objective problem fixed is a single space, which is definitely *too minor*. Edits should only be approved if they improve the post and this one didn't.

Comment: @bjb568: Fixing the insane indentation didn't improve the post at all?  Really?

Comment: @tmyklebu The help center article is about editing in general. Minor edits are obviously for 2k and self-edits.

Comment: @tmyklebu 1 space off is not "insane". No, the edit didn't help.

Comment: @bjb568: "Any time you see a post that needs improvement and are inclined to suggest an edit, you are welcome to do so."  We call them "suggested edits" when they're done by someone with <2k rep.  So no, that's demonstrably false.

Comment: @tmyklebu Um... it *needed* improvement? Removing the space is an improvement (tho so minor that it is a waste of time and bytes), but it is not a *necessary* improvement. Most people won't even notice.

Comment: @bjb568: Yes, it needed improvement.  No, the standard is not and has never been "is this edit *necessary*"---If it were, we'd reject all edits to barely-comprehensible typo-ridden questions as "unnecessary."  I'm a pretty careless reader and I noticed when I skimmed the post and I instinctively went through the code to make sure that was the only indentation problem.  The fixed code does not provoke that reaction.

Comment: @Tmyklebu "Yes, it needed improvement." "No, it's not necessary." Did you just contradict yourself there? If improvement is needed, how can it not be necessary? I do reject all edits too VLQ questions as "unnecessary" - you can't polish poop. If the edit is ok but doesn't fix enough, I'll fix the remaining problems (probably more work than the original editor) and uncheck the "edit is helpful" box. I don't know why you needed to check for more indentation problems, it looked fine to me and I don't even use that style.

Comment: @VotetoClose: You're talking to me as if I had no idea what the whole point of this discussion is supposed to be about. Yes, I know what "too minor" means. I'm saying there is nothing wrong with the edit, nothing wrong with the act of performing it, nothing wrong with the act of performing *solely this edit*, **nothing wrong *at all***. Is it finally clear that "too minor" was supposed to fall under the umbrella of this statement too? Please try to understand what I was trying to say instead of taking the words so literally.

Comment: @bjb568: Huuuh?  I don't believe I weighed in on whether the edit was "necessary."  Are you about to weigh in on whether the post being edited was crap?

Comment: @tmyklebu If you think the post needed improvement, and think the edit improved the post, doesn't that mean you think the edit was necessary? No, the post isn't crap (pretty obvious at +7).

Comment: @bjb568: That conclusion does not appear to follow from the premises.  Furthermore, it appears that you're trying to engage me in a semantic argument about the meaning of "to need."  This is not interesting.

Comment: @bjb568 One space off isn't insane. 25 spaces (6*4+1) off is. I don't know if I would have voted to approve, but I definitely would not have rejected it as "too minor", and if an edit suggestion *only* removed those 25 spaces, I also definitely would have voted to approve.

Comment: @hvd Changing indentation style from something some people like to another style that some people like is not an improvement, that covers 24 spaces of "invalid edit". 1 more space of valid edit is certainly too minor.

Comment: @bjb568:              The fact of the matter is that some people’s preferences are so bad that they look like pasting errors. This is one of those cases, and it really doesn’t make a difference whether it was        intentional.

Comment: @minitech The original post was a variation of [Whitesmith-style indentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Whitesmiths_style), and is the same as what we use here at work.  The edit was invalid _and_ too minor.

Comment: @Izkata: *“The fact of the matter is that some people’s preferences are so bad that they look like pasting errors.”* Doesn’t really matter if half of it has a name. See above for notes about the inconsistency in how the style was applied and the mysterious extra space.

Comment: @minitech Ahh, so why don't you write an official list of "approved spacing styles" and "preferred spacing styles"? Maybe make Community enforce them?

Comment: @bjb568: ’m tired of this thread, which is like a big circle of nobody bothering to read earlier comments. Au revoir.

Comment: @tmyklebu "Edits are expected to be substantial" -- removing a single space is not substantial.  Changing brace style is not a valid reason to edit.  There was no substantial problem with the original code, it should not have been edited, the edit should have been rejected.  If you fixed that **and** other contents of the post in the same pass, more power to you: if all you did was remove an extra space, then change the indent style... a review ban isn't a horrible result.  Edits have side effects (they bump posts, & suggestions notify 5 other people that the edit was made).

Comment: @bjb568 FWIW, *if* the extra indentation (except for the one extra space) was intentional, then I do agree that it shouldn't have been removed. The problem with that is that I see nothing in the question, the questioner's history, or the comments here to suggest that it was intentional. Not only (as noted here) was it inconsistent in that question, but the questioner does not use consistent indentation in other questions. So a mistake is more believable to me. (Just in case it's unclear, I do agree that the bracing style part of the edit was invalid, and the edit deserved rejection for that.)

Comment: @hvd Does it matter if it's intentional or not? It's easy enough to read and many people use that style. If the OP doesn't want it, OP can edit.

Comment: @bjb568 It's possible that this poster was an exception, but no, not many people use that style in C#. I have read enough C# code to say that with a certain degree of confidence, even though I am aware that it is more common in other languages. And for me, it did make it did make it harder to read: the original version requires more attention to verify that there is nothing odd other than the indentation. So based on an assumption that it was accidental, I do still support that part of the edit (the part that minitech had reapplied, not the rest).

Comment: @bjb568 BTW, first arguing that the edit was invalid because it changed the question away from the OP's preferred style, and then arguing that it doesn't matter whether it's the OP's preferred style is somewhat inconsistent to say the least.

Comment: @hvd Maybe not in C#, but people use it in other languages.

Comment: @hvd The problem is not about the OP. The problem is that it changed the style, period.

Comment: It didn't change the style, it added a style where there was none. Somebody please tell me, what the name is for indenting braces and double indenting the code block, and then inside the code block, not indenting braces and single indenting the sub-code block.

Comment: @bjb568: Because trying to axiomatise edits, reviews, questions, and answers is a fool's errand.

Comment: @Zook A mix of multiple styles? How is "no style" possible?

Comment: @bjb568 Semantics. Two styles in two total code blocks is close enough to randomly and arbitrarily indenting things. dOeS tHIs cOUnt As MULTIPLE capitaliZATion sTyLeS?

Comment: @Zook Are important. Which is fine since it's readable. Yes.

Comment: @bjb568 Fair enough. Doesn't change my opinion though, it's inconsistent indentation. If I saw it in my codebase I would fix it. On SO I probably wouldn't care enough in a code sample that short. If there were multiple parallel blocks such that blocks at the same level weren't indented to the same place, then that would be a readability problem and I would edit.

Comment: @Zook Agreed. It looks bad *to me* (not everybody) and I would change it if it was in my codebase. If there was a big block of random indentation, I'd also change it because it would actually make a difference.

Comment: @hvd You don't see it in the questioner's history because he's been being followed around by a troll who has changed the indentation style on all his posts - or at least, tried to

Comment: @Izkata: No, [the recent ones are like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049879/how-can-i-simplify-similar-method-calls-between-a-group-of-static-objects), deviating from the usual C# style only by the use of two-space indentation.

Comment: @minitech See BradLarson's answer on this question, and for a particular example [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24620229/revisions) (revision 29 and earlier)

Comment: @Izkata: What, this? https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24620229/1 That looks even more like a mistake. Plus there’s three-space indentation mixed in and missing spaces after the `if`. Revision 28 doesn’t have the excess indentation, and the OP seems to be fine with it, given all the other revisions. (And 29 has a diff error…)

Comment: @minitech The three-versus-four probably is, but my main point was that indenting braces on data containers (`class`, `struct`, etc) and not on anything else _is_ a consistent style, one I've seen before and that we use at work

Comment: @Izkata: Still hard to read, still not ban-worthy, still not definite, and I’ve gone and forgotten that I’d said I would stay out of this

Comment: @Izkata FWIW, I did look at the edit history of the questions I looked at before making that point.

Comment: Original indent style is correct for C#. K&R indent is not appropriate for C#. Edit was wrong, accepting it was wrong and ban was justified.

Comment: @Agent_L: Didn’t know there was a list of approved indentation styles for C#. Is 4/5 spacing on it?

Comment: @minitech: just my view, you mods need to get on the same page here and there's little point in a discussion on meta prior to you all agreeing what is the *current* policy that users might want to propose changes to. One mod informs people that it is site policy that it's unacceptable to approve an anonymous edit that just tidies up whitespace (aside from the fact that he also banned someone because of the trolling angle). You think precisely the opposite. This is one of the reasons I don't approve edits, ever. It's a task with no clear brief.

Comment: ... and I've given up even reviewing edits on my own answers. They invariably get approved by the time I've had a chance to re-read my answer and establish whether I think they're correct or not, so my approval bounces. It's better to wait until that's over and fix the answer if necessary. Anonymous edits are IMO a failed experiment.

Comment: @SteveJessop: It’s always acceptable to approve an edit – anonymous or not – that tidies up whitespace. What most of the disagreement here (by quantity) is over whether it this particular edit was an improvement or not as far as whitespace goes, since brace-style-only edits aren’t allowed. My major disagreement was with the ban, though, and Brad Larson’s answer addresses that.

Answer (score -3):

- The value of an edit does not come from the editor - him being a troll or not is irrelevant; Just like the identity of a poster of a question is irrelevant, we judge it by its content
- The relevant question is: did the edit improve the post?

I personally believe that the edit actually improved the post, the markup used previously is actually condemned by several styling guides. However, I can see the point that other style guides may judge differently.

- The opinion of the author is **irrelevant**, if we believe this to be an objective matter: either one styling practices dominates the other, or not.

For a comparison: English language has a somewhat unique "style guide" - corrections in language are also correct, if the author decides to purposefully use wrong spelling or similar.

So, we either

- Decide that there is a *dominating* code styling for the given language, and approve/disprove edits on that matter
- Or reject edits on these matters for being subjective/wrong/too minor

Comment: If we were to attempt to apply uniform styling to all code which style should we choose for each language? How many edit wars would ensue and the sheer number of useless post bumps for what is argueably a non-issue in a large number of cases. You'd be better off trying to convert emacs users to vim for all the good it would do and "help" it would give.

Comment: I agree with that, the list was rather for completeness. My main point is what I start with: Him being a troll or not is irrelevant to start with. (Moreover, changing this practice would make it absolutely horrible to actually audit edits: How should reviewers know?)

Comment: @FooBar the editor being a troll is irrelevant, agreed. The edit being wrong is the issue. To pick up the comparison to English, as a German native speaker I tend to create long sentences with many subsections and sometimes have interesting choice of words, yet still, my English is (mostly) correct. Fixing my typos is okay, fixing the style of my language is not - as long as it is comprehensible what I write.