# Review: All rules of the game

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, suggested-edits

I was going to edit my question on this [Approved suggested edit from a known troll?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265571/approved-code-review-from-a-known-troll), but I think it deserves its own question.

Where can I find the whole list of rules for reviews?

Comment: Now, this is tricky, as the site is community-moderated and (nearly) all rules have exceptions. The complete and nearly completely useless answer: Read all of meta (don't forget meta.SE), digest it thoroughly, and you are nearly there. Anyway, a good start is reading the help-center (especially the pages devoted to the edit privilige).

Comment: This is really too broad without a focus on a specific queue. I've narrowed it down to just the suggested edits queue here.

Comment: @Deduplicator: They would seem to mislead reviewers of suggested edits.

Comment: I think it's better if you don't think of it as a game.

Comment: @Dason I think it's better if you understood that using that particular wording doesn't necessarily imply that OP is thinking of it as a game ;)

Comment: @Dason No, I definitely don't think of this as a game, despite all the gamefication of SO. My wording on the title was more to get a list of requisites for a review. The help has a very generic list and my review was caught on a very particular set that I just wish I had known before.

Comment: Should this become a [tag:faq] (with a community-wiki list of ressources) instead of a [tag:discussion]?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Most of this is coming from the [Edit Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) privilege, with a bit added on:

> #### When should I edit posts?
>
> Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do
> so. Editing is encouraged!
>
> Some common reasons to edit are:
>
> - to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
> - to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
> - to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
> - to add related resources or hyperlinks
>
> Try to make the post substantively better when you edit, not just
> change a single character. Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged.

The big takeaways that I think are important here are teased out after doing so many of these edits, but this is what I've observed:

- There are few posts out there that only have one thing wrong with them; find and fix as much as you can.  When reviewing posts, cast a critical eye on the edit to see if there's anything else that should be fixed.
- Clarifying the meaning of a post without changing it usually includes not touching someone else's code.  For the question asker, it could be the difference between a breaking bug and something that's not reproducible (a-la Python); for an answer, it could change the context of the answer.  By and large, I've noticed that these are discouraged.

If you're ever concerned about an edit or a review, then don't feel ashamed to ask about a specific instance.

Comment: You might read Alexandre's other meta posts for further context.  Unfortunately the help centre's rules rarely reflect present reality.

Comment: I'd add something about "if your review requires approval make sure it is substantial and avoids incomplete/trivial changes like white space, *single* spelling mistake, removal of tags from title/thank you notes".

Comment: In particular, "to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages" should not be taken as license to change the meaning of the original answer. Instead, in the case of highly upvoted or accepted answers which are outdated and where the answerer does not appear to be active on SO anymore, a proper edit should clearly mark this status and suggest that other answers may have more up-to-date information.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's fruitful to pursue a comprehensive list of "rules" that you can expect to be faithfully enforced.  As a programmer, you have an intuition about what sorts of things make programming questions and their answers objectively clearer and more responsive.  When an edit does that, you should accept it.  When it doesn't, you should reject it.  There's a considerable grey area in between where you should use your better judgment.  Trying to reduce this intuition to a set of simple rules that a human would be capable of following is nigh impossible.

There are a handful of cases where your intuition leads you astray.  "Recommendation questions" are universally banned because of their uncanny ability to solicit spam.  (I'm not saying I agree that they *all* need to go away, but the line needs to be far closer to "ban them all" than you'd otherwise think.  Spammers really, really want to spam SO, and they'll seize upon even the most tangential connection to their product.)  You can often find useful guidance on these sorts of issues on Meta.  (Along with lots and lots of noise and vitriol for some reason.)

In your particular case, I don't think you did anything wrong.  It seems like a moderator was dealing with a bad actor, thought he could deal with some robo-reviewers at the same time, and accidentally scooped up a few legitimate edits and legitimate reviewers along the way.  This will happen; moderators are human and humans make mistakes.  (And I'm aware that this is not an emotionally satisfying answer!)

Comment: I totally agree with you. The purpose with my question wasn't to be nitty picky about it, but maybe cause a review of the existing text, making it more comprehensive. I understand that it will never be perfect, since we make the rules as we go... and as a result of actions from trolls, but I think they can be improved a bit.

Comment: @AlexandreSantos: The trouble with writing rules down is that a certain subset of the users will seize upon the written rules and use them to make people's experiences on SO hell.  You got caught up in a unilateral action by a moderator that, on balance, probably did more good than harm.  I'm pretty sure he didn't mean anything personal---at least not to you.  The thing to do (which is tough to do when you're in the middle of it) is to brush it off for what it is, maybe post on meta about it as you've done, and proceed as if it didn't happen.

Comment: Again, totally agree with you. Chalk it up to experience and move on.

Comment: @tmyklebu: Actually, don't *just* brush it off: Always try to find out the reason why it happened, and see whether you can make it less likely to happen again while following the spirit of the rules ("Make the internet a better place through creating a repository of high-quality programming questions and answers" it is here) (this advice is just about universally applicable).