# A user seems to be making a lot of unnecessary formatting edits

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

See for example [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5290279). This user has put several similar suggestions in the review queue. While I'm not against improving formatting, I definitely don't agree with the edit comment he's leaving on every single item:

> Exalt what you use to make your post more comprehensiveness

I mean, besides the fact that it makes no sense. My two questions are,

1. Does adding a lot of bold and italicized text actually improve the quality of a post?
2. Should we be doing more than simply rejecting these edits as "too minor"?

Comment: "Too Minor" implies that the edits are correct, just not enough to warrant an edit. These edits are blatantly **incorrect**.

Comment: I would agree on a couple words marked as code when he just meant to highlight them and vice versa. I don't know, is it always incorrect to add emphasis to a post?

Comment: When it is an incorrect use of that emphasis, yes. The only correct thing about the edit you provided was the capitalization of words. Everything else about it is just plain wrong.

Comment: At any rate, his latest two suggested edits have caused him to hit a 7-day edit ban. Huzzah.

Comment: Jeeze, and this guy is *still going*. Can someone please put a halt to this guy's `random` *formatting* **edits**? Edit: Never mind, animuson just took care of it. Edit again: Or did he? Was it a mod or a built-in thing? In any case, this person has been stopped, and hopefully won't start again.

Comment: Sounds like the system just did.

Comment: Yep, it’s the system. I don’t know why we can’t ban them manually with an appropriate message. (Sure, “the reviewers are a problem”, but there are a *lot* of reviewers.)

Comment: Thanks for checking and rolling back, @user3580294! I’ve handed out review bans of various lengths to most approvers.

Comment: Now if more people voted for it, maybe this would get implemented... [Meta.SE: Moderators should be able to manually ban users from suggesting edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221832/moderators-should-be-able-to-manually-ban-users-from-suggesting-edits)

Comment: @false No problem! Interestingly, that user's first few reviews were not bad, but they quickly descended into the *madness* of `random` **formatting** Edit: Tried to use zalgo, but apparently SO doesn't like that...

Comment: What's so bad about proper capitalization? And why has noone who visited the link or reviewed improved the question by him/herself?

Comment: @Trilarion Proper capitalization is good. I'm guilty of not taking the time to perform a correct edit on any of these. The issue I had was with seemingly randomized formatting changes, coupled with a nonsense edit reason.

Comment: > not exalting what you use to make your post more comprehensiveness

Comment: @AustinMullins: You're not "guilty" of anything; you have no _obligation_ to make better edits just because you've identified that the previous ones are sh!t.

Comment: I've seen that a good number of editors are under the impression that technical names for things (acronyms and product names) are best rendered in preformatted style. I will often ping them in the appropriate question and explain this is suitable only for (a) inline code and (b) inline console input/output. Excessive emboldening and italics are another pet peeve, and I'll sometimes revert them.

Comment: Oh no it's one of [*those*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back) people. Reject! Reject! Reject!

Comment: @NonExistent hey, we're all learners. That's why I asked the question here. It's not that you shouldn't edit anything ever. Read all the comments and answers carefully. Search related questions here on meta. Ask your own.

Comment: Ok, anyway, this helps, i'll try to make better edits from now, could you please tell what not to do when editing?

Comment: I think @Makoto answered that question well: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265579/1896761

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`No`. **Adding** *unnecessary* formatting **just** clutters `up` *posts* and makes them look ***messy***.

I personally flag as either *Invalid Edit* or *Vandalism*, depending on the severity.

When I see edits like that, I usually reject, go back, open up the post in a new tab to monitor it (in order to roll back if robo-approvers approve the edit), and take a look at the user's recent suggestions.

If more than 5 or so edits are similar in nature I will usually flag the question or answer they had approved edits on and select *Flag for Moderator* stating that the user is crapping out bad edits and needs to be stopped.

Comment: You mean, the bad reviewers must be stopped. Because atm the mods cannot directly stop the editor... See: [Meta.SE: Moderators should be able to manually ban users from suggesting edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221832/moderators-should-be-able-to-manually-ban-users-from-suggesting-edits)

Comment: I have seen many suggested edits like this and often amid all of the random re-formatting, they have left out spelling mistakes, small i's and often quite serious grammatical errors all of which are far more damaging to the readability of the post than the formatting suggestions -- properly indented code, is a different matter. I will usually click improve, uncheck the suggested edit was helpful box, only to find that the edit has been accepted once I click done. I am glad that there are some mechanism in place to stop robo reviewing.

Comment: @JohnBarça In that case I just uncheck the helpful box and accept the edit anyways to make sure the edit is rejected. Then I go back at my leisure and fix things without having to race against robo-reviewers. I really hope that's not an abuse of the system...

Comment: @user3580294 I like that idea and hope it's acceptable.  I don't like the idea of having multiple edits with my name a few minutes apart; but I've also found that racing the robo reviewers is mostly a losing exercise meaning there're 2 edits anyway and the robo editor ends up getting points.

Comment: @DanNeely If it's any comfort I haven't seen any complaints against it on Meta, but anything to fight against those robo-editors/reviewers, even if it's a losing fight...