# What should we do when someone makes lots of unnecessary edits?

Tags: discussion, documentation

Today I came across an user in the documentation who makes a lot of edits on different topics. In many cases, he just modifies the layout. To me, it looks like he is "farming" reputation by contributing a little bit to many topics and getting the reputation for the edit and every upvote in the future on the example.

What should I do in such cases? Would it be okay to reject the change with the reason "Other: change too minor and not really useful"?

Comment: Well, of course.  Crystal ball says that such users are eventually going to be banned from editing when this evolves out of beta.

Comment: It's silly to blame people for taking advantage of such an obviously game-able and broken system. Just let them do it. The sooner these things become ubiquitous, the sooner the Powers-That-Be will realize what a stupid idea it was to give everyone rep for such things. Remember: at 200 rep per day, it only takes 15 days to get close-voting powers. I can't wait to see what happens then...

Comment: Rep farmers do not like to close questions, @Nicol. It is like spraying defoliant on their rep farm.

Comment: "...change too minor and not really useful ..." The question behind this question: Are minor changes useful?

Comment: Problem here is the rep, not minor edits with the goal of rep-farming. If an edit improves a post then it is useful. Rep gains need to be changed, instead of stopping minor edits that do have value.

Comment: @Trilarion i think, minor changes can be useful, too. But when someone has multiple drafts with layout-changes pending it's likely that the user just wants the reputation.
I like Fermiparadox's idea. If the rep gains would be changed, many minor edits wouldn't need to be stopped. Minor changes should not generate reputation and the user should not be listed as contributor for changing the layout or fixing a typo. But it's hard to decide automatically, if a change is a minor change or not.

Comment: @FelixSFD same as people are doing edit question like removing , or adding space to just gain 2 rep. They are doing this whole day and not giving any answer but getting 2k rep :(

Comment: @NicolBolas Not sure that logic holds up really. Just because something is possible to do, doesn't mean you should do it. Just ask all those corporations trying not to pay taxes by exploiting loopholes. (admittedly it's less likely corps will get punished for it, but hopefully you get my meaning!)

Comment: Ask SE Management to [Remove or Overhaul Reputation in Documentation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329528)

Comment: See similar question on SO Q&A [A user seems to be making a lot of unnecessary formatting edits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265580)

Comment: Take a holistic view. If it's a change that is minor and it doesn't seem like intentional rep-farming, considering approving it. But if it's just adding some spaces or getting rid of contractions and/or the person has made several of these edits, reject it and don't give it a second thought.

Comment: I might be wrong, of course, but I think it is not worth to spend a lot of time fixing something that already occurred. For future actions new rules should apply, though. I think there is a large decrease in voting activity, therefore, maybe after 2 weeks or so there will be up to 5 votes/day, if not less.

Comment: @CodyGray "Rep farmers do not like to close questions" who said they are going to use the close votes, is the reopen ones that they will be burning.

Comment: @neminem Thanks for editing out the comma. This kind of comma mistake is bugging also me nowadays.

Comment: If only I could edit and replace an user with a user :(

Comment: That's simply an ad-hominem question.

Comment: Yes it's a big problem on stackoverflow, I constantly have to roll back unnecessary edits that make my question worse. That just add or remove a single word which makes a sentence that was already grammatically correct, _still_ grammatically correct. All done to game the system and get some points of reputation for adding nothing at all to the community.

Answer (score 59):

Keep in mind [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/documentation) reads:

> #### Anyone can contribute
>
> From whole new topics and examples to small copy tweaks, all improvements are welcome.

This indicates that "small copy tweaks" are welcome as improvements.

In other words, if it improves things without breaking anything, it should be approved. If you don't feel comfortable approving something like that, you should skip it (by reviewing other changes).

Comment: yes. Minor changes can be good, too. It's only a problem, if users start making lots of minor changes to get the "+2" rep and listed as contributor in lots of examples

Comment: I cant help but read this answer with a huge pinch of sarcasm. I hope this was intended?

Comment: @Persijn What makes you think that? I didn't intend any sarcasm. (Although the last sentence was supposed to be more along the lines of "there is no shame in using skip", until I remembered they don't have a skip button to use.)

Comment: Oh then its my bad. I read it with sarcasm since the question is about getting a lot of rep through small edits, and your pointing out just how easy and welcoming documentation ( and the tour) is when it comes to small changes.

Comment: @FelixSFD it's the reputation gain that's the problem, not the edit itself. It's great to have the possibility to fix minor problems like spelling, formatting, etc. on Q&A. I do not want to give that up. It's kind of like terrorism: just because some people do retarded nonsense in public should not be a reason to lock everybody up in their homes, although that would fix the problem.

Comment: @null Terrorism would be a destructive  edit, not an improvement, so it should be rejected. If you can't tell the difference between a rep-motivated edit and a quality-motivated edit: ["Mission F***ing Accomplished"](https://xkcd.com/810/).

Comment: To reverse the sentence, all *improvements* are welcome, no matter how small. If it's debatable whether it is even an improvement (or worse) then we ought to limit them.

Answer (score 26):

> To me, it looks like he is "farming" reputation

In [Demolition Man](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106697/?ref_=ttqt_qt_tt) there is this swear detector. And, no kidding, they actually tried to build a working version of it in a [github project](https://github.com/tdicola/DemoManMonitor). Maybe, one day, inspired by this, Stack Overflow will implement a rep harvesting detector.

Until then, we better not make any assumptions as to why someone edits an example. After all, [we're all motivated by reputation points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/56810/168269). I think that's the reason why we have a hard time seeing people who seem to be more motivated by it than we (make ourselves believe we) are.

So, **tl;dr**, simply try to evaluate if an edit is useful or not, without bias. If it isn't, reject it.

Comment: "... if an edit is useful .." Unfortunately this is not a trivial task in general. I guess at some point we will see some noise (i.e. edits get made without on average improving the content any more). And rep might unfortunately be the incentive to generate more of this kind of noise. It probably makes sense to be more strict for mature topics and reject everything that not significantly improves the content/layout in the long run.

Comment: Agreed, it's not trivial at all. I was focusing on the unbiased part. In my experience, all these hard tasks at Stack overflow such as evaluating close votes, low quality posts, revisions, and now everything that requires reviewing at Docs, is easier when you don't look at who it is you're reviewing.

Comment: *"After all, we're all motivated by reputation points."* I have to say [\[citation needed\]](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=2444230#2444230)

Comment: "we better not make any assumptions as to why someone edits an example"

Comment: Fat-fingered it and accidentally hit <enter> before finishing. Here is the the whole commment... "we better not make any assumptions as to why someone edits an example" -- I disagree. In one of my examples, someone changed a method name from plus5() to plus1() and moved some comments around. These meaningless edits were approved. Reviewers should be critical of so-called "improvements" especially when an example has been pinned.

Comment: @cb4 Still, it's only the quality of the revision that should be judged. The real problem is that people approve of crap. But I don't say that rep harvesting doesn't exist, of course it does. It's only that we never know when it plays a role. If rep greed and low-quality revisions are related (which is hard to prove) we'll discourage rep harvesting if we keep rejecting crap edits.

Comment: @GertArnold Yes! people are approving crap. I just read the Aug. 4th update and they're working on that. I realize that the experience of one person (me) is anecdotal, but I don't think it would be too hard to show a strong correlation between rep greed and low-quality revisions. Guess we'll have to wait and see if the changes fix this.

Comment: @cb4 I don't know. Too often I've seen hard facts contradict intuition. Although I must admit that (until the reward system is changed) it's probably too tempting to jump on a rep train by doing some minor edit.

Answer (score -3):

How about approaching it from a different direction:  Limit the % of your total rep score that can come from such edits, or make it a matter of diminishing returns once you go past a certain %.

Comment: Who or what classifies an edit in order to determine if it is "such"? Human or algorithm?

Comment: @Kaz Algorithm--small deltas can only make up a certain percentage of your reputation.  I wouldn't mind making it all edits can only make up a certain percentage--cleanup is useful but it doesn't show skill like getting upvoted does.

Answer (score -4):

Sounds to me like another guideline from the main site could be applied.  If you want to refactor something (or otherwise make systematic changes) throughout the site, bring it up on Meta first.

If you did bring it up on Meta, indicate so in your change comments, so auditors can see what you are doing and why.

By this model, these actions should be flagged, and the user's activity stopped until a discussion about the broader goal (as suggested by the OP, layout?) has been established by reasonable consensus.