# How do we define "substantial" edits?

Tags: discussion, documentation

G'day mates! One of my [edits on Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/73232?draftId=61250) was initially rejected (though later accepted without any modification) with the message: "Other: Please be more substantial with your edits."

It's true that my edit was very small; all I did was edit a single sentence to make it read more naturally. I did think about that very carefully at the time, but I thought (and still think) that the edit needed to be made.

After reading [Reputation Farming](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330267/what-should-we-do-when-someone-makes-lots-of-unnecessary-edits?cb=1) I was of the opinion that any edit that actually fixed something was welcome, even if it is only a small edit. On the other hand, I don't want it to appear as if I am simply rep farming or editing just for the sake of it.

So, is there a set limit that defines "substantialness?" Should I make sure my edits have a certain number of characters or meet certain guidelines in addition to being (I feel) an improvement or correction to the original?

EDIT: If you downvote please explain why. ;)

Comment: 1st of all primary rules: ***Don't edit turds!***

Comment: I don't think you can put a set limit on "substantialness" but I'd make the argument that your edit wasn't substantial. To me, it didn't improve the clarity. That's my metric for "substantialness".

Comment: Personally, I would expect a substantial edit to change the *meaning* of the content. Pure clarifications, while they might provide a minor benefit, are very subjective, and probably best avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Unlike Q&A, there's no reason for declining an edit as "too minor" in the dialog. I think this is because documentation is supposed to be polished and read by many users.
2. <s>Reasoning "go get 2000 rep and fix typos as much as you want without bothering reviewers" doesn't apply to Documentation, as all edits are reviewed, whether a user has 1 rep or 100,000 rep.</s> Edits of owners of appropriate silver and gold tag badges don't require reviewing now, so "go get silver badge and stop bothering reviewers" now applies in a way. :)
3. You only get reputation from "substantial edits" (criteria undisclosed), so nobody can blame you for farming rep if you fix typos — you only get +2 for that.

Now, you should still consider the fact that your edits require reviewing, there's no review queue, and approving your edit delays approving edits of other users. While changing "a result of the fact that" to "because" would made sense in a polished post in a polished topic in a polished Documentation website, it doesn't really look like something that you should spend your and others' time on right now. Most likely, this text will be changed many times anyway. So it's easy to understand users who are annoyed by tiny edits like this.

While Documentation is in beta and <s>most content is garbage</s> there're a lot of posts to improve substantially, it's a good idea to work on them. Readability can be improved later.