# Rejected flag about user making useless formatting edits

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, declined-flags

I flagged an editor who keeps adding random bold/italics/quotation/code formatting to posts, most of the time out of the blue.

There seems to be a clear consensus among the community and moderators that such edits are not OK. See for example:
[Are **edits** which `decorate` the post with > markdown good?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355183/are-edits-which-decorate-the-post-with-markdown-good)
[A user seems to be making a lot of unnecessary formatting edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265580/a-user-seems-to-be-making-a-lot-of-unnecessary-formatting-edits)
These threads have, by meta standards, an almost overwhelming consensus with very few people disagreeing on this moderation policy.

Yet the flag was declined:

> User x is repeatedly making completely superfluous and incorrect formatting edits to posts. Seems he's been doing this a long time too - long history of similar "vandalizing" formatting edits. – Lundin
>
> declined - While some of the edits lack a certain style, overall the edits of this user appear more useful than not.

The user is active and has [65 suggested edits since August 1st](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4933696/anurag-sharma?tab=activity&sort=suggestions&page=1). Because of the rejected flag, I now manually checked every single suggested edit. Out of the 65 edits, I can find less than 10 that don't contain nonsense formatting and can pass as useful — mostly these were code formatting-only edits. But the vast majority of their edits is just a form of vandalism, most likely for the purpose of farming reputation.

It seem pretty clear to me that this user needs a nudge so they stop doing this. Most of those edits are in need of rollbacks. So what am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe more worrying is that most accepts are caused by OP's approving them.

Comment: Even if `(somehow)` you agree with adding the [styling](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), the edits do seem **very** minor and give off a **very** _reputation farming_ vibe

Comment: @rene Indeed, this seems to be a common problem overall.

Comment: @George there are not "very minor" edits, there are not "minor" edits. Stop that. Either the edit improves the post or doesn't, focus on that.

Comment: @Braiam There are indeed minor edits, they could edit a post to include a few full stops, maybe add a few apostrophes, while this may _improve_ the post from a punctuation perspective, it doesn't really add much and could stop some lower rep users from actually adding a significant improvement on post as they'd have to wait for it to be reviewed. So although they do improve the post they could actually be detrimental.

Comment: @George again, Shog killed the "minor edits" when he removed that reject reason. Stop using it as qualifier. You shouldn't think whenever an edit is minor or not. **Focus on whenever it improves the post or not.**

Comment: @Braiam You seem to be missing my point, I'm **not** saying minor edits should be rejected, they're fine as edits, but when they have to be reviewed and approved and can potentially hold up other more substantial edits, then they become pointless but not bad, but not great edits in my mind. Just to reiterate, I'm not saying minor edits should be rejected, just discouraged unless the edit doesn't have to be reviewed (which I think is 2k rep) Also I'm not talking about the edits in question, like you I'm talking about edits in general.

Comment: @George *you* seem to be missing my point. Continuing to qualify a edit as minor, however that should be defined, is perpetuating something that SE wants to explicitly eradicate. One should stop calling any edit as "minor" altogether. SE wants everyone to focus on whenever an edit improves the post or not, as the sole indicator of quality of an edit and don't even consider anything else.

Comment: @Braiam The reject reason *too minor* might have been removed but some edits are still *too minor*, they fill up the queue and usually don't fix enough to actually make the post good. And George is just saying (as I understand it at least) is that these minor edits are fine but not if you do minor edits for rep farming by suggesting a lot of them (and thus filling up the queue).

Comment: Based on your situation I'd say this needs an explanatory response from the rejecting moderator. Have you considered adding a [meta-tag:support] tag to the question?

Comment: I told the user to stop in a comment and it seems like he understood that what he was doing was bad.

Comment: @EpicKip Read the FR Shog did explaining the change" If it's really too minor, **reviewers should demonstrate that by providing a not-minor edit**. If the reviewer opts to build upon the edit instead of starting over from the current revision, then it isn't too minor!" Basically, if the reviewers consider something as "too minor", then they should provide a better edit. Since a better edit is provided, the previous one isn't one that improved the post. Otherwise, whatever is called too minor actually isn't.

Comment: @Braiam I've had the same discussion with you before, you try to put the fault of the editor on reviewers. An edit does not become good or substantive when a review decides he can't/won't fix the mess (I will reject a very very minor edit instead of improving it if I know nothing of the topic say c++ or php)

Comment: And this meta post continues to gather upvotes when the OP has given no evidence of any edit.

Comment: @Braiam they have, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4933696/anurag-sharma?tab=activity&sort=suggestions&page=1) is in their post and will direct you to all of the user's edits. A few specific ones https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17216352, https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17209281, https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17209040

Comment: You're missing the classic [Reject an already-approved suggested edit when rolling it back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back) on MSE from your list of examples.

Comment: @George you know who else keeps doing worthless edits? [This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions&page=1). Pointing towards a user profile is not evidence. It's saying "there's a problem there, figure out where".

Comment: @Braiam but the issue is, it's not just something wrong with one or two of their edits, it's to do with most of their edits. So pointing to a user profile (Which they shouldn't have to do as the flag is on an action that user has done) should be fine. I'd image a mod would appreciate just that rather than 50 links. It's like saying there's snow on the mountain over there, pointing to it should suffice, you wouldn't be expected to climb the mountain and pick up some up to bring back to show.

Comment: @George So, because you edited several post in a short burst without knowledge, all the weight of the hammer should fall upon you? Yeah, forget about communicating to the user first so they can't claim they were told before, right.

Comment: @Braiam _It seem pretty clear to me that this user needs a nudge so they stop doing this_ a nudge does not mean they are permanently banned, Communicating to the user is what we want.

Comment: @George is a moderator needed for such "nudge"? Donald Duck was able to give a "nudge" without blowing up out of proportions nor needing a moderator. Why should it be escalated to a moderator?

Comment: @EpicKip It's a link to the current logged in user, they are just using it to make a point rather than to insult anyone.

Comment: @George Aha, no point is made however (as a user profile full of bad edits is actually evidence) but thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @Braiam because when it's said by another user it can be taken as an opinion if you told me my edits were bad, I may not care, whereas if I was told by a moderator it would come off more like a _rule_. (I'm not saying that we should just abide by everything moderators say no questions asked, but their words of warning hold more weight)

Comment: @George ha! Moderators do *not* make rules. They may enforce one, but they do not make them. Here's one example of [a moderator disagreeing with a **freaking rule that Shog made** just because, instead of enforcing it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356147/declined-flags-on-removed-old-vlq-answers/356148#comment511090_356148), which causes users confusion. So, please, don't be so naive.

Comment: @Braiam Hence why I said "more **like** a _rule_", also you contradict your own point, moderators don't make rules but Shog made this rule, Shog is a moderator.

Comment: @George What...? Treating Shog as a moderator just remembers me how clueless people are about SE workings. [Shog is not a moderator but a community manager](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341/213575). Moderators are usually elected, CM's are employed by SE. Shog, bluefeet, Tim Post are the most nearest official voice of Stack Exchange.

Comment: And what's wrong with moderators (or anyone, really) disagreeing with a community manager? They aren't gods. The meta-rule is that the site is ultimately moderated by the community, so if the community is in staunch disagreement with the CMs, then it makes perfect sense for them to express that. If the CMs really want to *prevent* us from doing something, then they'll have to remove the option, not simply post their opinion on Meta.

Comment: @CodyGray in this case, it's a moderator disagreeing with a very sensible rule if we are to have anything similar to quality. It's one man with tons of power enforcing rules the community *doesn't want*.

Comment: @Braiam "... enforcing rules the community doesn't want.". I'm not sure he's really acting against the community here, based on the voting distributions, sorry to say. I'm not thrilled that the consensus seems to be against 'minor' edits being valuable, and I tend to agree with you, but this probably isn't the best way to support the cause. At this point you may want to consider just making a separate thread going into all of the details of Shog's original reasoning behind getting rid of "too minor" rather than these side answers and comments, to give it the best chance possible for success.

Comment: @jrh I think I was too subtle with my wording: the community doesn't want a rule that lowers the quality of the site. He's enforcing a rule that does exactly that.

Answer (score -61):

***Forget this specific case, here's what you should do in posterity.*** You shouldn't flag users for "useless formatting edits". You should flag users for:

- vandalizing (and the reviewers for approving such edits);
- introducing plagiarized content; or
- hurting readability consistently

You didn't flag for any of those reasons. Unless you can demonstrate that an editor is reducing the quality of a post, you shouldn't issue a flag and instead just rollback the specific edits you believe reduced the quality of the post.

As a rule of thumb, ask yourself this: are those posts better now than before?

If yes, use that as evidence. That would give the moderator something concrete to work on, otherwise your flag would be declined.

Comment: @Braiam, how is this answer any different to the one you deleted a minute ago (other than some formatting differences within the last paragraph(s) and the bolded title)?

Comment: Why I don't mind talking about the general in the comment I think this question would be better suited to an answer that addresses these specific edits, which in this case the "useless formatting edits" would fall under "hurting readability consistently". FYI the penultimate sentence is still phrased incorrectly.

Comment: @Rob I think you answered yourself. It has a freakish big title that nobody can claim that didn't read.

Comment: @George and I believe that OP should provide evidence on his flag. Which again, this answer, main point, anyone?

Comment: @Rob Braiam asked me  to remove my comment, as they believed it was causing people to misinterpret their answer. A similiar thing has, in fact, happened to me as well. So I am sympathetic to this concern.

Comment: @Braiam I believe mods are quite capable of going to a user's profile and looking at their edit activity,  I would assume they'd do this even if you did link a few edits to make sure you're not just picking a few out.

Comment: *Because you shouldn't flag users for doing "useless formatting edits".* Citation needed. At best, that seems an overly broad misinterpretation.

Comment: @George why, mod as busy as they are, should do this when the user raising the flag which is more than capable to do the same?

Comment: Why the heck the commentary that explained quite clearly the difference between my previous answer and this one removed?

Comment: @MartijnPieters why should a moderator care about that? Ain't more pressing issues than a user complaining about the other user for stuff they didn't like but aren't explicitly prohibited?

Comment: I'm having trouble thinking of issues that would be more pressing for a moderator than a user suggesting bad edits and people approving them. This causes damage *all over the site* that is very difficult and very disruptive to repair. It's a lot worse than a comment-posted-as-answer here or there. It's *certainly* a lot more pressing than a bunch of "no longer needed" flags on comments.

Comment: @CodyGray because it's not systemic. Remember the time when moderators were supposed to be exception handlers? What do kind of exception it is if the user can simply roll back the edits? And even then, nobody communicated [with him until recently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356140/rejected-flag-about-user-making-useless-formatting-edits#comment511030_356140).

Comment: Rolling back the edits doesn't solve the problem at its root. People who consistently approve bad edits should be instructed and possibly banned from reviewing for a period of time. People who consistently suggest bad edits should be similarly instructed and banned from editing for a period of time. None of these are things that a normal user can do, which is exactly when a moderator steps in. I know you think all reviewers are clueless buffoons, but I still believe that a series of erroneous reviews is an exception.

Comment: @CodyGray where did you saw evidence on the flag that OP raised that there were a reviewer/group of reviewer doing that? Where?

Comment: I didn't look. I wasn't the moderator who processed that flag. The point is, this is the type of thing a moderator *should* look at, so I'm disagreeing with your claim that it is not.

Comment: @CodyGray you don't even understand my claim, how can you disagree with it?

Comment: @CodyGray but the title of this question talks about *useless* edits, not *bad* edits. The latter should of course be flagged, but is even the first category of edits flag-worthy?

Comment: @user000001 Useless edits that require approval are bad edits.

Comment: @yivi [citation needed]

Comment: Are you seriously defending that useless edits are not bad edits?

Comment: @yivi not always, they can be neutral, indifferent and many things other than bad.

Comment: @user000001, if they are useless and require resources to deal with them, they are bad. They cost something and we get nothing, since we've already stablished that they are useless.

Comment: @user000001: There's a reject reason for edits that don't improve anything. Thus it is codified that useless edits are bad edits and should be rejected.

Comment: [Your comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356140/rejected-flag-about-user-making-useless-formatting-edits#comment511076_356146) looks like an answer. Why it is not? @CodyGray

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt because it's not an answer to the complain on the OP, but towards the argument I'm presenting.

Comment: I didn't like how you were shouting in your post so I took the liberty of formatting it. Ironic, isn't it?

Comment: This answer is right on the mark. I do not understand the 'downvote hell' here? It makes no sense to group edits by their size, either they add value (however small) or they don't. Reject the ones which does not add value.

Comment: @Repmat There is no "downvote hell". Simply most of the the community that passed through disagreed with this answer's point of view. [Voting is different in meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). The rational for treating minor edits that require approval differently than more significant edits (or edits that do not require approval) has been explained several times in this thread, in the question thread, and in elsewhere in meta.

Comment: @yivi What the heck are you reading?????? You don't even read the freaking first line!? I **do not care about that edit**. I take an issue with OP using "useless edits" as reason to bother moderators.

Comment: @yivi then stop [trying to sound like you do](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356140/rejected-flag-about-user-making-useless-formatting-edits?cb=1#comment511380_356146). You don't even understand the main point of my answer, yet keep telling users what should be interpreted.

Comment: I think you are replying to a comment I had to delete, since your original comment with numerous question marks was lacking details. You've updated it since, making my other comment obsolete.

Comment: Still, passing moderators have disagreed on being "bothered" with this, the consensus is, apparently, firmly against your POV, and I for one don't care for your tone and manner. There is no need for this level of vehemence and language. Please, try to be more respectful of your peers.

Comment: @yivi I'm being plenty respectful. I'm not calling your mother nor I've made a personal issue with anyone. If anything, I'm refuting the moronic argument that everything and anything should be escalated to moderators, which isn't being disrespectful, just calling ideas by what they are, considering that moderators are exception handlers, that you should call upon *only* when you are unable to deal with a situation.

Comment: @Christian What Braiam already said. I was just disagreeing with what he posted in comments here, not with the answer itself. I agree with the first line of this answer, that you shouldn't flag users for making "useless" edits, and I generally agree with Braiam that there isn't really such thing as "too minor". If an edit makes a post even slightly better, then it should generally be approved. The part I kinda disagree with comes a bit further down; specifically the implication Lundin's flag was not for a user that was consistently making edits that hurt readability, thus introducing harm.

Comment: Furthermore, I have "investigating this situation" on my to-do list, and an answer of my own will be forthcoming (dealing specifically with Lundin's flag, not generic advice) when that happens, unless another moderator does so first. Been pretty busy today, and currently still working through 100+ inbox notifications... :-)

Comment: @CodyGray when in the world I imply that "specifically the implication Lundin's flag was not for a user that was consistently making edits that hurt readability"?

Comment: Uhh…everything after the first bolded phrase. You said he didn't flag for vandalism or hurting readability. It sounds to me like he did. I consider setting random words in bold and/or as code to be vandalism because it decreases readability.

Comment: @CodyGray no, he flagged for "useless formatting edits". That's the very title of this meta question. The text of the flag goes in the same vein. if the text instead reads "The edits of this user has been hurting readability as seen on [link] and [link]. He has ignored reaching out in [link to comment] and continue to do so." it would be a valid moderator flag and one that anyone would be hard pressed to decline (given that evidence is factual).

Comment: @Braiam useless **formatting** is vandalism, or else it would not be useless.

Comment: @EpicKip "useless" comment is rude, or else we shouldn't flag them, right? See. Useless is not a useful metric to evaluate edits.