# Should I accept an edit that adds information to an answer?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, edits, answers

I found this [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5301519) on that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481973/heroku-error-permission-denied-public-key/3482054#3482054).

The edit adds a paragraph about some test that the original poster did not find necessary to include. Shall I:

- accept it because it may be an improvement
- reject it as a radical change

In case the suggested edit disappears, here is the original answer:

> Try `heroku keys:add <path-to-your-public-key>`. For example, `heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

and the proposed added paragraph:

> To test if this works correctly :
>
> ```
> ssh -vT git@heroku.com
> ```
>
> The above command could also reveal if git searches for keys in a wrong directory. In which case setup your `HOME` environment variable to `~` ( which will be `C:\Users\UserName` in `Windows` )

Comment: I would reject it as an **invalid edit**, it should be a comment to the post. We are not supposed to change someone else's answer like that without permission from the author.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion: I agree with you. The problem is that comments cannot be correctly formatted, and posting it as a new answer would have been *plagiarism*.

Comment: Given the original answer was intact and augmented with relevant information I don't understand why you shouldn't accept this edit. Specifically, `This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost` is not true as the original meaning is `not lost`

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion _"We are not supposed to change someone else's answer like that without permission from the author"_ [is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). It's improving the answer by adding examples, you don't need to ask the original poster permissions for that.

Comment: @CodeCaster That information is plain wrong as far as per my knowledge of GIT and heroku. That command is to check domain. Apart from the technical aspect, it is simply an invalid edit. I will formulate an answer to explain more.

Comment: @Infinite if it's wrong you're right, it shouldn't be accepted. I don't know enough about the subject to determine that. Were it factually correct, the edit would have my approval, as it attempts to properly expand an existing answer. I just reacted to that sentence of yours, we do not need to ask permission from OP to add information to answers.

Comment: @CodeCaster Even for correct info, it is acceptable only if it is to "updates as the post ages", i.e. related to newer versions/changes of software. How can adding commands for testing be considered as valid edits?

Comment: @Infinite _"How can adding commands for testing be considered as valid edits?"_ - it is a test to verify what is stated above it in the answer. It makes the answer more usable (if it were correct). The "aging" is irrelevant here.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion: The command is not that stupid. It effectively simply checks domain, but mainly ensures that `ssh` is correctly configured on client. According to my own experience it may be useful for beginners using Windows ...

Comment: @SergeBallesta True, I meant plain wrong in the context of the question. OP says Mac in question, also the other answers have plenty of info, including official doc links. I don't think it's an appropiate edit. It could be posted as another answer, mentioning "In addition to XYZ answer by ABC, I would like to add..."

Comment: In my opinion this is an invalid edit. This is just _suggesting_ a test, suggestions belong in comments. A clarification would have been if the OP had: _"you can verify this command was successful by using ssh with the vT options"_ and the editor then put in the command and an explanation of what the command was doing.

Comment: Those reviewers deserve a break from reviewing for approving this edit.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion : Am I drunk, or had you posted an answer with many links that I no longer see ?

Comment: You are drunk ;-)

Comment: I was getting toooo many comments. People who believe in editing were commenting. Who will answer so many comments on this topic? It has been discussed to death on Meta already...so...deleted it. Peace. :-)

Comment: @CodeCaster You should really read the page you just linked to, becauase it states the exact opposite of what you're claiming.  To quote it, edits should "to clarify the meaning of a post **without changing it**".  Edits that change the meaning of a post are not appropriate.

Comment: @Servy adding an example does not change the meaning.

Comment: @CodeCaster But it doesn't just add an example.  It completely rewrote the entirety of the answer, leaving only the example that the OP originally had.  The edit was radically changing the actual content of the answer, and that's not acceptable.

Comment: @Servy what you see here is the proposed _addition_, and the discussion in the comments became more broad than just this example.

Comment: @CodeCaster: If a suggested edit requires domain expertise to evaluate, it's an inappropriate change in meaning.

Comment: I got a very similar edit approved and then reverted back by the OP, because I was not supposed to edit someone else answer.
The result is that, in my case at least, the correct answer is spanned across 2 answers... Confusing, at least.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should be commenting on the answer, and let the poster of the answer update his answer as he sees fit.

First of all, SO should be encouraging users to post different answers, no matter how small the differences are. People seeking the answer can then decide for themselves which one to use, based on upvotes as well as their personal preference.

Secondly, if an answer is incorrect, downvote it.

Editing an answer with what *you* deem to be an improvement is the same as stuffing salad down someone's throat because you think it's healthy. If you politely remind the poster that he could improve it, he can then choose to accept that improvement or not.

The only edits I usually approve are formatting (significant ones, like wrapping code blocks in ... code blocks), significant grammar improvements (e.g. capitalizing will not get my approval, unless it's an essay), and typos in code.

Comment: Agreed. I happy accept comments to my answer and in some cases I will add them to the answer itself. But if someone adds a chunk of extra information, or changes it significantly, I'm happy to revert that change, except when it adds value *and* I completely agree with it. But in that case, I still think it is impolite.

Answer (score 24):

You should not even think about accepting such an edit unless you can be sure that the information being added is 110% correct, which usually requires being an expert in the field of the question. Allowing an edit which adds potentially incorrect information has consequences for the reputation (both numeric reputation score, and in terms of how other SO users perceive them) of the answer's author. It also degrades the quality of the site by making such incorrect information appear authoritative based on the answers' existing upvotes and/or the reputation of the author.

Comment: Answers don't belong to the poster, they belong to SE. Any user can (suggest to) edit any answer. While edits like this should be carefully evaluated by people with enough knowledge on the subject, I think they're perfectly fine as opposed to duplicating the same answers over and over again or spreading knowledge over multiple answers. SE is a wiki, not a forum. Granted - edits like addressed here will usually be made by users having enough experience and according reputation to bypass the edit review queue and apply the additional knowledge immediately.

Comment: @CodeCaster: To go with your wiki analogy, to be valuable as a source of information, a wiki needs some system of citation and/or accountability. On SO, this is achieved by the votes on the answer and the reputation of the author of the answer. Adding random possibly-incorrect information into a highly upvoted answer by a 50k user undermines this. No, answers do not "belong" to the poster, but to be fair both to the poster and to users of the site, the informational content of an answer should not be changed significantly from what the answer's author wrote/intended.

Comment: On several occasions I've had to rollback serious misinformation added to my answers by inexperienced users. I don't blame the users who added it (they were new and didn't know better) but rather the reviewers who approved the edits. I really wish we had a feature where edits to answers with at least +10 upvotes or where the author has >10k rep would stay out of the public edit queue (visible only to the original author) for 2-3 days and only go up for community review if the author does not approve/reject within that time.

Comment: I think you're overestimating the significance of votes here (I see _plenty_ of upvotes that must have been cast while thinking _"Cool, I do not understand this"_ or _"Thanks, this oneliner saved my day"_, where the answer itself is _bad_ in terms of explanation, reusability, architecture or even correctness of code shown). Anyway let's not assume the premise every edit to an answer is incorrect: are you advocating that answers should never be edited to add additional information or explanation, other than updating them when the answer has "aged" into being incorrect?

Comment: I'd hesitate to say "never". Certainly there are cases where adding content is appropriate, like where the author has cited an external site/document but did not quote the relevant paragraphs they were referring to. On the other hand, I've (multiple times) had answers I wrote edited to change C function names into links to the pages on cplusplus.com about the functions, and more than once the linked page had errors that directly conflicted with the content of the answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster Your assertion that you don't own the answer is false.  You *do* own your own answer when you post it to SO.  You are simply giving SO the right to redistribute that content even though you own it.  Additionally, regardless of whether or not it is obligated to by law, SO's rules specifically state that edits to a post should only be to change the presentation of the author's existing content, and should not be used to change the content of the answer itself.  Radically changing a post is unacceptable, regardless of the technical accuracy of the edit.

Comment: @Servy then that's my misunderstanding, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

> Shall I:
>
> - accept it because it may be an improvement
> - reject it as a radical change

You're missing option #3:

- skip it because I don't know the subject well enough to *know* it's an improvement.

If you *knew* this was a valid addition to the answer, you could approve the edit without concern; if it was an edit you might in good conscience make yourself, then *why not?*

The problem is, you clearly *don't* know. I'll sometimes spend a significant amount of time researching a topic before editing (or approving an edit) just to allow myself to do so in good conscience, but if I don't have that time... Then I've no business rubber-stamping the edit.

By the same token, you don't know it's a radical change either...

Answer (score 8):

I usually reject edits that add information that wasn't part of the original answer, even if it's in a domain that I'm fairly knowledgeable about.

The reason is that the new information could be incorrect, or I don't always have the time to verify the veracity as a domain expert. New information should really only be added as comments, or as entirely new answers (except for, perhaps, *exceptional* circumstances, like security vulnerabilities that need to be prominently displayed).

When rejecting such edits, I'll leave a comment for the editor explaining why the edit was rejected, and suggesting that they add a comment or a new answer.

#### Exceptions

I might make exceptions for cases where a change has been discussed or mentioned in the comments already.

Comment: If you don't have time to verify the information, is it not sufficient to ignore the edit and wait for someone else to review it?

Comment: @dcorking you can't trust that someone else will notice. I've seen bad edits sit around for *months*, even a year or two, before I finally noticed them and undid them. Stack Overflow just has too much content. We can't police every single item all the time. You have to take actions at the moment that you see a problem, otherwise it's likely that no one else ever will.

Comment: Thanks @Cupcake. I mistakenly thought that edits waited in an approval queue.

Comment: @dcorking edits *do* go to an approval queue, until you have 2000 reputation, at which point [you can make edits without going through the review process](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). But you can't trust that other people will also verify the correctness of an edit (nor have the expertise to do so)...this is known as the "robo-reviewer" problem here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

It should have been a comment on the existing post. I would reject it as an

> Invalid edit : This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post."

As per **[Help Center > Privileges > Edit Questions And Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)**

> **When should I edit posts?**
>
> Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do
>   so. Editing is encouraged!
>
> Some common reasons to edit are:
>
> • to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
>   • to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
>   • to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
>   • to add related resources or hyperlinks

#### Related posts:

[Why is it bad to suggest edits that add additional information to answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191114/why-is-it-bad-to-suggest-edits-that-add-additional-information-to-answers)
[Reviewing suggested edits - what is an invalid, incorrect or radical edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218183/reviewing-suggested-edits-what-is-an-invalid-incorrect-or-radical-edit)
[Add info to the help center stating what not to edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187493/245167)
[Is adding extra information to the question considered a good edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167968/245167)

Comment: That is not what the [help] says. It says that **you *can* edit "to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages"**, which contradicts your reference.

Comment: _"to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it"_. Adding instructions on how to use / verify what is stated in the answer is clarifying it without changing it.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion You stated in your comments on the question that the added information is incorrect. You should add that information to your answer.

Comment: I don't know why so manz are fixated on the "Some common reasons to edit are:" list. Clearly it expresses that the list is not complete. So it does not matter whether this scenario fits a specific (listed) case or not! The rule also *clearly* states that "Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do so. Editing is encouraged!". In case there is no explicit rule banning specific edits everything is allowed (except: there still might be more general concerns like Intellectual property)

Comment: That's better only if it's a community wiki, else without author's consent, we shouldn't edit extra information into a post. On SO, a post is closely related to author's profile. e.g. It affects **author's reputation and credibility** if someone edits some information into author's answer. They can leave a comment, author will add it to the answer body, if required. Else they can post their own answer.@BatteryBackupUnit

Comment: It is entirely author's choice in terms of content and style of answer, if anyone disagrees, they can downvote or post the correct answer. also, they can leave a comment. That is why community wikis are there @BatteryBackupUnit. A non-wiki answer belongs to the author of the post. Preferential editing by other people leads to edit wars.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion I understand that viewpoint and i even agree with the logic. I think that there's a conflict of interest (author profile vs quality of answer) which is not easily resolved. What i wonder however is why we even allow edits by 3rd party, then. If author's profile is that important, at least every edit would need to be accepted by the author. That's not the case, is it?

Comment: There is no conflict of interest, anyone has better content should post a new answer. You can always write "In addition to XXX answer, I would like to add YYY". Editing is a priviledge to help others, not go around forcing our thoughts on other people's content. We should limit our opinions to our posts or community wikis. Generally, those who post answers know better on that topic, that's why they bother to answer in the first place. Those who suggest edits have low rep, and may not know the software properly. If we trust our knowledge and care about quality, we should post an answer @Battery

Comment: They allow third party edits and send it for human review, and we have guidelines saying reject based on XYZ criteria. If it's a valid edit which improves and doesn't disturb content or style, it's useful, isn't it? @BatteryBackupUnit

Comment: @Infinite Recursion Yes i agree (with a small reservation), i was rather aiming for the "you may update an outdated answer", which was suggested to be a viable edit. If one agrees with your opinion though, one should be consequent and have all edits (except to community wiki) be reviewed by the original author. There's no point in others reviewing the edit. The post is linked to the authors profile / credibility etc. and he should have sole control over it.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion since a lot of questions are about "may i accept this edit" it seems unclear what these guidelines are. The guidelines are hard to maintain and hard to control. Often edits are accepted even though they may be factually wrong (incompetent reviewer). Since the post is tied to the original author, he should be the sole person to authorize edits. Others may pitch in and recommend acceptance or rejecting as a help to the author, but not more. Otherwise "Generally, those who post answers know better on that topic, that's why they bother to answer in the first place" is flawed.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion also see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265574/review-all-rules-of-the-game?cb=1 The first comment basically states that it's a huge undertaking to know the rules / guidelines. This is really unattractive for newcomers.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you @BatteryBackupUnit. Updating outdated answers are good and we should approve. It is in the guidelines too. However, in the context of the edit which the OP mentioned in this particular question, I asked others how it is an update, and [everyone](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265689/should-i-accept-an-edit-that-adds-information-to-an-answer/265692?noredirect=1#comment61402_265689) wrote it is **not and update of outdated technology**. Technology update related edits are valid, I agree :-)

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit Yes, that post refers to how it led to an edit war due to style preference. One guy is **forcing** his style on another. As I told earlier, [It is entirely author's choice in terms of content and style of answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265689/should-i-accept-an-edit-that-adds-information-to-an-answer/265692?noredirect=1#comment61444_265692)

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion no that's actually where i disagree. If authors profile is that important updating outdated answers is plain wrong, a new answer should be posted instead! The particular edit in question may have been right or wrong, but my take is that this discussion did not actually center around establishing the value of the edit but rather if it was generally viable to accept additions or not. Now i think that value is of more concern than where it stems from. If, however, authors profile is more important, then there should be *no* edits *unauthorized* by the original author, *ever*.

Comment: Hmm.. Food for thought. Might be a good feature request then :-) @BatteryBackupUnit