# Should we be able to flag suggested edits?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, suggested-edits

[This approved edit is what's prompting this suggestion/question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5321940)

### TL;DR

- Let users flag suggested edits for review
- Automate review bans based upon flag outcomes

---

### What's the current situation?

As many meta regulars are likely already aware, there seems to be a problem at the moment with "robo-reviewers" blindly approving edits which have no business being approved. When this happens, someone with enough reputation needs to head over to the question that was edited and then roll the edit back to the previous version, which is a 2k rep privilege.

Ok, but what if I don't have enough reputation to perform the rollback myself? It's *possible* that the edit could slip by unnoticed by any users with sufficient reputation to undo it.

### How can we improve it?

Allow us to flag *completed* suggested edits (both approved and declined) for review if we feel that the chosen action was incorrect. This would allow lower reputation users such as myself to flag these bad edits for the attention of more experienced members who can then perform the necessary corrective actions, or decline the flag if there's no problem.

There's also some use for this for higher reputation users as well. If they see a bad edit approved, they can also flag it for review if they feel that it was a result of robo-approvers (see next paragraph for why they may wish to do so).

### Automating review bans for poor reviewers

If this were implemented we have the potential to use this as a way for automating review bans. If a certain proportion of a user's *recent* edit reviews end up being flagged and subsequently deemed incorrect, a temporary ban could come into force without diamond moderator intervention.

### Other Consequences

There are two main ones that spring to mind.

- The user that suggested the edit should have the +2 rep revoked if the edit was later deemed invalid.
- The user that suggested the edit could get edit-banned if they are consistently submitting poor edits that manage to get through and are later revoked (in addition to the current edit ban criteria).

### New Review Queue

I'm envisaging something similar to the Close Vote Queue, where you need multiple people to agree on what should be done before anything happens, perhaps 3 users?

The queue itself would require at least as much reputation to access as the Suggested Edit queue does, but I'd actually say it should be higher than that. Perhaps 5k?

The thing I'm not sure about is what should happen when a higher reputation user raises the flag. Should the question/answer in question be locked from editing while the flag is active? Or should they be able to go on ahead and rollback as usual, potentially acting as judge, jury and executioner? Input on this would be appreciated.

### Intended long-term effects

In the long term, this could serve to reduce the number of robo-reviewers, as if they continued to review as they currently are, their automated bans would simply get longer and longer each time. Either they'd have to improve their reviewing style and become valuable reviewers in their own right, or face the prospect of not being able to review at all, thus moving that shiny badge they're so concerned about further out of reach - and lessening the number of dud edits that make it into the system.

Comment: I too have noticed a that people keep making non-beneficial edits, similar to your example, where they just introduce superfluous code tags around every single IT term like `console` and `MS Access`, and similar formatting that actually helps little. They get through way too often.

Comment: Yes, rollback _is_ [a 2K privilege](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120583/245167). It comes with full edit privilege which is gainedat 2K.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: Rollback isn't actually that useful as the user often has hundreds of edits to rollback. I had to rollback around 80 edits by a user a few days ago which was full of `impruved formeting` (sic). About your proposal, doesn't this feel like "meta-review"?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Surely in that situation the problem is not that the user suggested 80-odd crap edits, but rather that (up to) 240 users incorrectly reviewed them? This perhaps is a meta-review of sorts, but given how many edits that get through that shouldn't, is that such a bad thing?

Comment: The cynical part of me thinks we wouldn't have to wait long to see robo-reviewers in the new "anti-robo-reviewer" review queue.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist To be honest that had crossed my mind as well, which was part of the reasoning for making the rep requirement 5k instead of 2k. I don't really know how much of a barrier it would be to robo-reviewers though, it might even need to go higher than that. Maybe 10k or 15k.

Comment: @JonK The significant effort that has gone into investigating the problems with suggested edits has shown that there is virtually no correlation between the quality of a reviewer and how much rep that they have.  The idea of a queue like this has been suggested dozens of times, and there is no reason at all to believe that it would be any better than the existing queue, even if the rep requirement was raised.  The same bad reviewers will be reviewing their own bad reviews, and nothing will improve.

Comment: @Servy Hmm, I had looked on this meta to see if had been discussed before and found nothing, but I *didn't* check Meta.SE, and [fairly quickly found it over there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101538/add-ability-to-flag-a-user-or-suggested-edit), thanks for pointing it out. Now I want to be able to close as a cross site duplicate (which I *know* has been discussed previously) but alas, I can't...

Comment: @AnthonyGrist If anything, it'd probably be flooded worse than the other queues.  The robo's who've left the others after getting the golden internet point from them will be rushing the new one too.

Comment: As Brad wrote in his answer, problematic reviews are really most of the times due to personal preference. It's not due to robo-reviewing. A recent example was [this meta discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265689/2982225) which is very similar to your question's edit. An answer with 2k+ votes was "edited for improvement". If you read it, you will understand that it's not robo-reviewing problem. Many users support these kind of edits. The community has two different opinions of right and wrong.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion It does indeed - and I'm firmly on the side of "you shouldn't edit someone else's answer just to conform to **your** personal preferences". That's the thing that bugged me about that edit - changing `IPredicate` to `Predicate` was *completely unnecessary*, and doesn't improve the post in a meaningful way. That said, it's an interesting discussion, and I'm probably going to be busy for a while yet reading around on this.

Comment: Just don't stat collect (at least user visibly) or have badges on the meta-reviewing and I think the robo reviewers will just ignore it, not pollute it.

Comment: You will find a lot of these discussions @JonK. The common reason why all measures seem to fail to control robo-reviewing is because it isn't robo-reviewing. It's a concious decision by a section of reviewers. Quoting from Brad's answer - " The more common problematic edits we argue about now tend to be matters of personal preference.., not someone clicking an "approve" button blindly."

Comment: Quit building problems on top of problems. Remove the source of the problem - remove the review counters and badges. Un-gamify the process. While we're at it, remove the 2 rep from editing, or lower the cap severely (500? 250?) Less pointless reviews, less robo reviewing.

Comment: What about edits that didn't go through the review process?  I just encountered an especially poor one that I wish I could flag somehow.

Comment: The irony is it's very easy to build up rep by making these redundant edits which enable you to continue making these redundant edits with full approval. The privilege to edit should really be about English ability rather than rep.. It should definitely be possible to flag terrible edits too because they occur way more often than the good edits.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A similar suggestion [was proposed here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223947/can-we-have-a-system-to-submit-potential-robo-reviewers-for-moderators-attention), and as you can tell from [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223967/135615), I'm not entirely opposed to it. I think easing into this by giving moderators an internal "leaderboard" of reviewers with flagged reviews first would allow us to see how much noise there is in these flags. If these flags do seem to track with poor reviewers, we could see about feeding this into the system.

I'm not as much of a fan of review queues for moderating reviewers. I believe that user moderation tasks should be left to the system, the community managers, or elected moderators.

Beyond manual flagging of reviews, I'd like for the system [to more intelligently take into account what happened to reviewed posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223212/135615). If someone has said "No Action Needed" on a post that was later flagged and destroyed as spam, I want to know that. If they do this more than once, we may need to step in.

It's also a real pain to go back through a reviewer's history and delete mis-approved spam, so for more aggressive cases I might be useful to invalidate reviews from certain reviewers and have items go back into review in bulk.

I should say that problems with bad accepted edits are not a new thing, in fact I think things are a lot better off than they used to be. Before audits were put into place, it was often a 50/50 chance whether outright vandalism and spam would be approved. Now, it's a fairly rare occurrence. Like plane crashes, we think it happens a lot more than it does because the cases of this tend to get a lot of attention on Meta and elsewhere. The more common problematic edits we argue about now tend to be matters of personal preference (some people think `code` `formatting` `everywhere` is just fine), not someone clicking an "approve" button blindly.

For now, if you see a really bad edit being approved, flag the post and we'll look into it, rolling back and dealing with reviewers as needed.