# Not sure how to handle this unkind suggested edit

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, specific-edit, unfriendly-or-unkind

My options on reviewing [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/31675730) don't give me the opportunity to draw the moderator attention it deserves, which is that the person that made the edit probably needs a time-out.  There's no option to mark the suggested edit as unkind.

What should I do when encountering a review like this?  For now, I just rejected it.

Comment: Reject > Causes Harm. Raise custom moderator flag.

Comment: [Should we be able to flag suggested edits?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265917/1426539)

Comment: @Larnu, where shall I raise the flag?  On the question?  It's the _edit_ that needs attention.

Comment: On the question (or answer) itself. Raise a custom flag and explain what happened.

Comment: No, raise it on the answer, not the question. And again, be *explicit* on the reason and link to the review.

Comment: You can raise it anywhere you want. It's not particularly material for custom moderator flags. What matters is that the flag message itself included the necessary information/links so that the mod knows where to look.

Comment: Perhaps they wanted to comment (or vote) and couldn't due to the [50 reputation points threshold](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/)? And this was a way to circumvent it (even a meta comment on the situation)? Or a protest against a question ban (e.g., due to deleted posts)? Or related to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67780906/how-do-i-draw-triangles-between-the-points-of-a-fibonacci-sphere/67783219#comment119823290_67783219) a while back (there could more recent ones on deleted posts).

Comment: Wow. Just wow. Looks like it got them a one-week suspension. Seems lenient, frankly. Thank you for making sure action was taken on it.

Comment: I mean. The user icon is a trollface. Makes me think a week timeout is not going to do very much.

Comment: I would argue that that suggested edit was outright abuse, not just unfriendly/unkind.

Comment: That wasn't a suggested edit as much as it was hate mail from a Modern Warfare Xbox lobby full of angry twelve-year-olds with negligent parents.

Comment: Don't use the custom reject reasons for these. Use "spam or vandalism" as that would feed the user into the Spam Ram.

Comment: "Unkind" I would call it more than just unkind!

Comment: Vandalism, insults, antisocial & unprofessional behavior, and suggestion of suicide… "Unkind" doesn't even begin to cover this.

Comment: i'm quite surprised the account that wrote that still exists, feels a bit disappointing to consider that someone who would write something like that isn't immediately removed entirely

Comment: @a_local_nobody If the account is removed, the user becomes more difficult to track than if the account is retained and suspended. Rest assured that moderators are on top of this.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

As a couple of the comments stated, Rejecting the edit is the first thing to do. After that, raising a flag for moderators is the next step. You should raise this on the post with the inappropriate edit and be clear what you are flagging for because a suggested edit isn't clearly shown in the moderator flag queue. We only see the text you type. A suggested example:

> This post had an inappropriate edit (LINK). It's been rejected, but the edit suggestion itself was harmful.

With text like that (and the provided link), I can clearly and quickly see what the problem was and take action.

Comment: Does rejecting the edit prevent the post author from seeing it in their inbox? If not, is there something that can be done (by a moderator or otherwise) to make sure they don't see it?

Comment: @Laurel Does it really matter? The edit was rejected, the user was suspended, they were likely notified *why*, and if they try it again the edit would be rejected again and they'd likely see another suspension, *hopefully* longer in length for a second offense.