# Spent two hours improving an answer, 20 seconds later it is rejected?

Tags: support

I spent a considerable amount of time updating an answer that was totally broken, out date, and useless.

Since the edit was rejected within 20 seconds, it would have been utterly impossible for anyone to have actually read or considered what I wrote, or what needed correcting.

No only was this rejected, without any notice, message or other communication, all my points were stripped. Seems not only a bit harsh, but unproductive. Is it not good to try to encourage users? Teach them? Frankly, I can't learn if no one communicates, nor would I think anyone else learn using these methods.

Clearly communicating what happened to my edited post would be appreciated, as well as why I got slapped with no notice or explanation.

---

The review for the edit in question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5337209).

Comment: Was the question deleted, or the answer? If just the answer was deleted, do you have a link to the question so the users with 10K+ rep can take a look? Also, by "updating", was this an answer of your own, or were you editing someone else's answer? In any case, it sounds more like coincidence than a targeted takedown...

Comment: Did you change the meaning? If so, it might have been better to add a new answer.

Comment: After some research, it appears we are talking about [this suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5337209). Nothing was deleted, only the edit was rejected.

Comment: You didn't edit; you rewrote the answer entirely, and that's wrong. Your edit was invalid, and should have been rejected.  You don't get "points" until the edit is accepted, so they weren't yet yours to "lose" and so you didn't "lose" anything". You don't get reputation ("points") in advance here; the contract says you have to edit and have that edit accepted before you earn the reputation, and that didn't happen. (And if the reason you're  editing is for "points", you should stop immediately, because that's the wrong reason.)

Comment: Sorry you spent so much time polishing that turd.  I should have deleted the whole mess rather than just close it :/

Answer (score 33):

After taking a look at the review in question, here's my take on things.

> I spent a considerable amount of time updating an answer that was totally broken, out date, and useless.

That's usually a good thing. However, after a certain point, you aren't *editing* a person's answer, you're *rewriting* the answer. If your edit gets to the point where the stuff you added is *longer than the original post* (or even before you reach that point), you really should consider making your own answer.

This is because major edits that add or remove significant amounts of content or otherwise substantially change the content of an answer are not allowed, unless the post is community wiki. This has been covered elsewhere in MSO ([here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265744), for instance) and stated much more eloquently, but part of the argument is that you're effectively putting words into someone else's mouth, which really isn't too polite, and could be nonconstructive if you're incorrect.

> Since the edit was rejected within 20 seconds, it would have been utterly impossible for anyone to have actually read or considered what I wrote, or what needed correcting.

To be honest, the reviewers really don't *need* to read what you did. If a reviewer is greeted with a *massive* wall of text as an edit to an answer, they're almost certainly going to reject it, simply because it's not a valid edit to make.

> No only was this rejected, without any notice, message or other communication,

Yes, you don't get a notification; why, I'm not sure. I believe this is by design; why exactly, I don't know. I can speculate, but that's not the main concern here.

> all my points were stripped.

Not really; you just never got the points you would have gotten for your edit had it been accepted. Not quite the same thing.

> Seems not only a bit harsh, but unproductive. Is it not good to try to encourage users?

It's not harsh at all. You shouldn't get rewarded for an invalid edit. The reward is to encourage *valid* edits (which may or may not be working, depending on who you ask).

> Teach them? Frankly, I can't learn if no one communicates, nor would I think anyone else learn using these methods.

Seems like what you would like here is a notification when an edit has been reviewed. I'm not aware of any feature requests for this, and I'm somewhat skeptical that this would be implemented. Unfortunately, you seem to be stuck with manually checking the results of your reviews.

> Clearly communicating what happened to my edited post would be appreciated

You can go to your profile, click on the "activity" tab, click on the "suggestions" box, and look through your edits to see the results of reviews for your edits. There you can find (some) feedback for your edit.

> well as why I got slapped with no notice or explanation.

Well, you have your explanation. As for the "No notice" part; unfortunately, I can't provide an authoritative answer about that. You can consider a feature request, but I'm not certain that that would be taken too well.

---

That being said, sorry to hear that you ended up wasting a lot of your time. As I said before, *major* "edits" like that would more properly go into their own answer. However, as you probably noticed the question is closed. Why?

To prevent things just like this from happening.

While your edit would have made the answer correct at the moment, eventually your answer would have met the exact same fate as the answer you tried to edit. Allowing this would result in some wild inconsistencies across the site ("Why is *this* question hideously outdated, while *this* question is always up-to-date?"), and in general isn't too productive without constant care, which isn't likely to happen outside of the most common questions, damaging the quality of the site.

As the question has now been deleted, it's a bit of a moot point. But please don't take this personally; take it as a learning experience. Just a few pieces of advice (with thanks to Ken White):

- Edits should not make substantial changes to content/message/etc.
- Think carefully if you want to edit an on-hold or closed question. If you can edit the question to the point that it is a good, clear, on-topic question for SO, by all means go ahead do that (with the caveat that you don't change the original intent/meaning of the question, of course). However, sometimes the question is on hold/closed for a good reason --  questions like homework dumps are hard to edit because you can't make the post substantially better without input/effort from the OP. Editing those is generally a pointless exercise.

Comment: This is an excellent answer (+1) with one disagreement. With regard to your first bullet point at the end, you're wrong about not bothering to edit on hold/closed questions. If you see a question that is on-hold or closed and you can clarify it to make it a good question and help it get reopened, you should by all means do so (with the caveat that you shouldn't change the actual meaning of the question). Advising people to just not bother is wrong, and goes against the entire spirit of allowing posts to be edited here. The advice in that bullet is simply wrong, IMO; I edit them often.

Comment: @KenWhite That was what the "good reason" was for. Questions like homework dumps, crimes against the English language (although posts were OP's question is truly indecipherable are not too common), and other total messes are kind of hard to edit because you can't really make the post substantially better without input/effort from the OP. You have a good point, though, about on hold/closed questions in general. May I add that to my answer?

Comment: Certainly. :-) I agree with 99.999% of what you said, though. Again, excellent answer.

Comment: @KenWhite And done! Does that address your concerns?

Comment: Very much so. Nicely done. I take back my objection. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for Michael Myers finding the link to the suggested edit you did. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5337209

Most reviewers will not accept an edit that adds/removes a lot of stuff from an answer.

Simply go to the question, copy/paste what you edited, make any other changes you seem fit, and then add it as your own answer to the question.

**UPDATE**

It seems as though that question is closed, so not possible to add an answer.

What you could do in this case if you wish, is to start your own question, try to make it a good question. **ONLY do this if you can make the question acceptable to what is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on SO.**

And then simply add your answer to your own question.

Comment: Stack Overflow simply is not a good place to keep track of this information, so I wouldn't advise creating another question. It will just get closed and deleted like this one.