# Can we unlock this answer?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, locked-posts

I had come across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24620229/5735775) which has been locked because of content disputes:

[image]

This had actually been locked because of [an edit war](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24620229/revisions), which happened way back in July 2014. This post has now been locked for nearly two years (1 year, 9 months), and the question and answers were also last active 1 year ago. [The conflict](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263115/when-is-it-okay-to-edit-answers-for-code-formatting) has cooled down. I think it is right to unlock this post.

Doing this will be good because I want to make a typo-edit to the post, which right now I cannot (not the kind of edit the war was started on). I think none of the users in the edit war remember this experience, and nothing would happen if we unlock it.

Please tell your opinions if why / why not this answer should be unlocked?

Comment: Can locks be made to have an optional time limit set on them? Seems like that would be a great way to prevent this from happening again in the future.

Comment: @Ajedi32 As I recall, that's already the case. And if you look in the history of that post, you'll see Community unlocking it several times- That's from timed locks. The timed locks apparently weren't helping, so the post was just locked down long-term. Looks like it's been long enough to help. (Let me find a ref for that timed lock thing.) Edit: [Here's a question specifically about timed locks, for instance.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124748/locked-time-note-has-a-wrong-wording)

Comment: Using the correct brace style is serious business.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but did you just ask for a question to be unlocked to correct a typo that was bugging you ?

Comment: @Nico: Not at all. I wanted to unlock this post , and fixing the typo was one of the extra reasons; even without the typo thingy, I would've wanted to unlock that answer.

Comment: For more context on the trolling that led to this lock: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265571/approved-suggested-edit-from-a-known-troll/265592#265592 . This trolling unfortunately has resumed: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13372194/revisions http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5124769/revisions , possibly as a result of this post.

Comment: @BradLarson: If you think that this post is again starting troll edits, you can delete it. I am totally okay with that. But please do not lock that answer right now. If even after deleting this meta post, troll edits are continuously being done, for lots of days, you can lock the answer. But please first observe if more troll edits are happening on that answer before locking it. You can delete this meta-question any time you want.

Comment: @BradLarson more effective method to make this stop: ban the reviewers...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I agree. I've unlocked the answer.