# How does this edit not make the post more readable?

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

I am curious why [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12151534) edit has been rejected.

It clearly improves readabillity by fixing the formatting and it even fixes a typo. This happens to me often and I wan't to know how people think this is no improvement.

Should I even edit posts to fix typos and such formatting?

Comment: The edit is still pending...

Comment: @Rizier123 true but Im curious why people would reject it.

Comment: Has it been rejected or not yet approved?

Comment: @Paulie_D someone has rejected it. On other occations equal edits have been rejected fully

Comment: It looks fine to me. I'm not familiar with c# but the only thing I can think of is the layout of the code changed...no idea if that's important .

Comment: @Paulie_D its better this way - no reason for extra indention.

Comment: ...oh, and there are some bad reviewers out there.

Comment: @Paulie_D I guess its just that then.

Comment: what about this: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12151470

Comment: "wana use". I'd like more proper English there - "want to use". Code formatting should be done with care, although in C# it's usually safe.

Comment: You've left quite a lot of room for improvement there. It's not a bad edit, but it's not a particularly good one. As the reject reason picked states, your edit doesn't really make the post any better. The changes are superfluous in light of other changes the post would benefit from.

Comment: I improved the edit. No idea what to make of _"as it the state."_, though.

Comment: Regarding [the other edit suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12151470). If the only problem with a post is the "Thanks in advance", it's hardly worth editing - certainly not on posts that are inactive. If you really want to remove it, it's better to wait until you have full edit privileges (on SO, 2000 points or more). The edit is not technically wrong, but is probably considered too minor ("changes are superfluous").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reviewer who rejected it, probably felt that too little was done to improve the post. As was pointed out in the comments, there were a few other things that could be improved.

In the distant past, reviewers had a "Too Minor" option for rejecting edits. Since Stack Overflow removed it, some reviewers have used the "No improvement whatsoever" option as a substitute for "Too Minor". The harsh wording of the "No improvement whatsoever" review option, [has been the subject of discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242159/the-new-edit-rejection-message-for-no-improvement-whatsoever-sounds-too-hostil).

To answer the more general question:

Fixing typos is OK - it's a good reason for editing.

Formatting is tricky. As a rule of thumb, it's better not to format someone else's code style. In this case, your change in formatting was an improvement. However, there are also editors who want to change other people's valid formatting style to the style they prefer. When the formatting styles are equally valid, then it should just be left alone.
(This is actually very similar to another rule - we don't change American English to British English or vice versa).

In fact, [changing code style has been used to troll users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265571/approved-suggested-edit-from-a-known-troll), which is why reviewers may choose to reject such edits right away.

When formatting code, you should realize that in some languages indentation has meaning. For example, Python and Haskell. So if you're going to format code, then do it only to languages you're familiar with.

Comment: That clears up some stuff, thank you