# Disallow Edits from Unregistered Users

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits, anonymous-user

While suggested edits can be useful, I feel that we should limit these to *registered users*. This will prevent unregistered users from trolling these edits.

Here are a couple examples of these suggested edits from unregistered users:

[Suggested Edit # 1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19145448) | [Suggested Edit # 2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19146213)

These are **obvious** attempts to deface the posts on which these edits were done. While I wait for some eye-opening data from Shog9 on how many suggested edits were declined as "deliberately destructive" in regards to *Registered Users* vs *Unregistered Users*, I think we can come to some consensus as to whether or not we should keep these edits from people who are active in the community (hence, those who take the time to create an account).

I am not asking for a minimum-rep increase, as I feel that anyone who is willing to put their name on an edit should be allowed to contribute to making changes for the better; but if you are unwilling to do the bare minimum in creating an account, why should we consider your edit?

I feel that those who willing to positively contribute to editing posts are those who already have an established account on Stack Overflow.

What are your thoughts?

---

<sup>**Related:**

[Approved suggested edit from a known troll?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265571/5781745)</sup>

Comment: While I agree those edits can be a nuisance the review option that is in place should prevent any mishaps. It becomes only an issue when those edits get approved in which case we need to address the reviewers. I think it is a value that we allow non-registered users propose improvements, very much like wikipedia does. But I'm open to look at Shog9's data to learn if I need to adjust my view on this.

Comment: I agree that they can be useful. All I am asking for is some _minimum accountability_.

Comment: Accountability doesn't matter as long as you are under 3K rep user as you can't really hurt the site without being peer-reviewed first (like rene said). The only potential problem I see here is if someone posts hundreds of bad edit suggestions which can increase the queue and prevent from people reviewing the other edit suggestions. But like you said, we will need to wait for Shog to show us some stats.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Just a check, full edit privileges come at 2K. Is your 3K just a slip of the key or is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: @rene Bad memory mostly

Comment: @DavidArenburg you should get it replaced ;)

Comment: I asked for this [a long time ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78899/144883).  I looked for a while at what those "additional restrictions" might possibly do, but decided that the esteemed authorities are not respecting my free time enough.  The average lifetime of a reviewer at SO is only a month, not so sure that they are expendable resources.  Wikipedia does it, somehow.

Answer (score 7):

No, let's not do that.

Up to now a total of [135,626 edits have been suggested by unregistered users](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/824533), with 73,568 approved. That is a bit over a 50% success rate.

If I look at how reviewers handle those suggested edits you'll find this:

```
approved rejected approved by OP rejected by OP vote     
-------- -------- -------------- -------------- -------- 
169418   27485    10631          6              Approval 
28354    158447   0              1814           Reject
```

There doesn't seem to be a blatant approving of such edits so in my book that can go for the minimum accountability.

Since [13 May 2017 suggested edits only requires two votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349125/578411). Here are the stats since then:

```
2 votes needed
approved rejected approved by OP rejected by OP vote     
-------- -------- -------------- -------------- -------- 
12623    1349     1844           6              Approval 
1886     9516     0              324            Reject
```

Again not a great shift in numbers, nothing significant at least. (But I'm sure a statistician is able to spin this the other way around.)

**TL;DR**

There is nothing in the actual numbers that reveals a pattern that these edits are out of control. As still the majority of those suggestions are approved by either the OP or the reviewers I don't think disallowing them would be a correct measure in this moment in time. As long as the balance is on the positive side that these edits add value to our content I would refrain from disallowing such edits.

When the numbers get dramatically worse I'll reconsider.

Comment: Thanks, how that compares to the registered users stats?

Comment: @DavidArenburg you can run the SEDE query I linked and replace `where se.owneruserid is null` with `where se.owneruserid is not null` to get those stats. I surely hope it won't turn out that we need to disallow suggested edits from registered users ....

Comment: Welp, it looks like registered users have ~82% approved edits, maybe accountability does matter after all...

Comment: I see a 50% failure rate.  Your glass is half-full, but at what failure rate do you consider a feature to be unproductive?

Comment: @HansPassant I think there are two metrics involved then, failure rate should be down to say 25% or lower and further declining **AND** the remaining reviewers (those that didn't burn-out) don't get to legit reviews anymore. But yes, I'm a glass is half-full guy. I admit here that I'm a bit disappointed/concerned as well ...

Comment: I don't get why you have a vote column... what does it means if you already have an approved/rejected column?

Comment: @Braiam those are the review approval/rejections, so it tells you something about how many *approved* suggested edits, got an reject vote during review.